# Establecer atajos de teclado en botones de menú

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy estableciendo el típico menú de "Editar" en, valga la redundancia, un Editor de Texto que estoy haciendo para practicar con Python.

El menú de [Editar] tiene las típicas opciones de:

- Deshacer
- Rehacer
- Cortar
- Copiar
- Pegar
- Seleccionar todo
- Preferencias

  ```
  # ...

  # Menú-de-Barra :: Menú Principal
  menubar = Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
  self.config(menu=menubar)

  # >> Submenús para el Menú Principal
  #   -> tearoff=0, para que no salga un elemento vacío por defecto
  #   cuando no hay submenús del submenú

  editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
  menubar.add_cascade(label='Editar', menu=editmenu, underline=0)

  # >> Submenús para el Menú Editar
  editmenu.add_command(label='Deshacer', command=self.edit_deshacer)
  editmenu.add_command(label='Rehacer', command=self.edit_rehacer)
  editmenu.add_separator()
  editmenu.add_command(label='Preferencias', command=self.edit_prefer)

  # ...

  frame = Frame(self, bg='black')
  frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
  frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

  # ...

  frame_txt = Frame(frame, background='black')
  frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W+E)

  # ...

  self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
  self.text_01 = Text(frame_txt, wrap=WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
  self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
  self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font, selectbackground='lightblue', width=44, height=16, bg='#242424', fg='white', insertbackground='white', highlightbackground='black', highlightcolor='white')
  ```

Ya sé que, estableciendo la propiedad de `undo=True` dentro de la configuración del Text de Tkinter, es posible aplicar la acción de "Deshacer" y "Rehacer" con la combinación de teclas de "CTRL+Z" y "MAY+CTRL+Z" respectivamente (al menos, en Ubuntu).

Pero me gustaría saber cómo sería que al pulsar el botón de menú de "Deshacer", se efectuará la misma acción que al pulsar la combinación de "CTRL+Z". Lo mismo para el botón de menú de "Rehacer".

Y las acciones equivalentes a "Cortar", "Copiar", "Pegar" y "Seleccionar todo":
- ¿cómo se realizan?
- sé que, para indicar una combinación de teclas en un elemento de menú, se establece la propiedad de `accelerator='CTRL+O'`, para un menú de "Abrir archivo", pero, ¿cómo es que, al pulsar una combinación de teclas se aplique una determinada función o acción? Esto para acciones como, "Abrir archivo", "Guardar", "Cortar", "Copiar", "Pegar" y "Seleccionar todo" ... Creo que tiene que ver con cierta función de `bind()` o `bind_all()` (no estoy seguro). Pero no sé, exactamente, cómo se aplica.

Creo que eso es todo. Espero que alguien pueda sugerirme algunos ejemplos. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto *copiar*, *pegar*, *cortar*, *deshacer* y *rehacer*  son características ya implementadas en el widget `Text` y tienen su propio evento ya asociado a la callback correspondiente. Por lo que basta con que generes el evento correspondiente siempre y cuando lo habilites con el argumento `undo=True`, por ejemplo:

```
text_widget.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
```

No obstante, tal como comentas puedes usar [`bind`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) para asociar un evento cualquiera a una callback. `bind_all` es exactamente lo mismo pero la asociación se extiende a toda la app, no solo al widget. Esto lo puedes usar para asociar una combinación de teclas para las funciones *seleccionar todo*, *abrir*, etc o para sobrescribir o extender las características anteriores.

Un pequeño ejemplo, que implementa las funcionalidades *copiar*, *pegar*, *cortar*, *deshacer*, *rehacer* y *seleccionar todo*, cada una con su combinación de teclas y su comando en el menú `Editar`. Además las opciones  *copiar*, *pegar* y *cortar* también están disponibles en un menú contextual al hacer click derecho en le texto. Para mayor facilidad, todo se ha encapsulado en una clase propia que hereda de `tkinter.Text`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

####### Python 2 #######
#import Tkinter as tk
#import tkFont  



def beep_error(f):
    '''
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    '''
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        '''
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        '''
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Cortar", command=self.cortar)
        menu.add_command(label="Copiar", command=self.copiar)
        menu.add_command(label="Pegar", command=self.pegar)
        menu.tk.call("tk_popup", menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<SelectAll>>")
        #self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')   # < Otra alternativa
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'



class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Editar', menu=editmenu, underline=0)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )

        editmenu.add_command(label='Deshacer',
                             command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                             accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                             )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Rehacer',
                             command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                             accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                             )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label='Cortar',
                             command=self.text_01.cortar,
                             accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                             )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Copiar',
                             command=self.text_01.copiar,
                             accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                             )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Pegar',
                             command=self.text_01.pegar,
                             accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                             )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Seleccionar todo',
                             command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                             accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                             )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota**: `return 'break'` es la forma que tiene Tkinter de bloquear la propagación del evento de forma ascendente al resto de widgets del árbol.

---

### Edición

Si quieres llamar a un método de un widget padre desde un widget hijo tienes varias posibilidades, pero quizás la más apropiada sea generar un evento virtual que puede o no se capturado desde cualquier widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Ejecutar proceso", command=self.ejecutar_proceso)
        menu.tk.call("tk_popup", menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    # Genera un evento virtual que puede ser capturado desde otra parte de la app
    def ejecutar_proceso(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<EXEP_Event>>")



class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<<EXEP_Event>>', self.ejecutar_proceso)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )


    def ejecutar_proceso(self, event=None):
        print("Ejecutando....")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

El nombre dado al evento virtual puede ser cualquiera siempre que respetemos los dobles paréntesis angulares:

```
"<<cualquier_nombre>>"
```

Podemos ver una lista de los eventos virtuales predefinidos que existen en:

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/event.htm#M41

Comment: Con la forma que tengo de importar el Tkinter (me refiero a `from Tkinter import *`) que creía que facilitaba el no tener que incluir la referencia de `Tkinter` o `tk` si pones alias, al crear a un widget, es decir, tk.Frame o tk.Text, al final eso me facilita al teclear pero me complica otras cosas que no sé como resolver. Por ejemplo, cuando llego a líneas como la que has puesto, en la función de "deshacer" de `self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')`, como yo no establezco el "import Tkinter as tk" sino el "from...", si quito el tk, me da error de que este método no está disponible. ¿Solución?

Comment: Has considerado que todas las funcionalidades referidas a las acciones del Text llaman por callback a respectivos métodos que están en la propia class MyText. Y si, por ejemplo, pusiera en ese menu contextual que has montado otro submenu que tuviera que llamar a un método `def ejecutar_proceso(self)` dentro de la class MainApp ¿sería como sigue? [en el def __init__ de MyText] `self.bind('<Control-b>', MainApp.ejecutar_proceso)` y [en el def mostrar_menu] `menu.add_command(label="Ejecutar", command=MainApp.ejecutar_proceso)` ¿sería algo así?

Comment: Otra cosa, ¿me puedes pasar una referencia de dónde encontrar una lista dónde salgan todas las posibles teclas estilo <Control-z>, si es <Supr> o <Del>, etc, ...?

Comment: Primero, no uso nunca en las respuesta los imports con wildcard (`*`) porque es una mala práctica excepto en unos casos muy concretos, por legibilidad de código, porque puebla sin necesidad el espacio de nombres actual y porque puede provocar solapamientos inadvertidos de namespaces y errores inadvertidos por por ello. Dicho esto, esas líneas no debes tocarlas aún importando como haces, si te fijas el identificador `tk` está precedido de la referencia a un widget (`self`, `menu`, etc), por lo que su espacio de nombres es diferente, es decir deja igual `self.tk.call`, `menu.tk.call`, etc.

Comment: En cuanto a la segunda duda, si vas a hacer referencia a un método/atributo de la clase padre usa el atributo `self.parent`, `MainApp` hace referencia a una clase, no a la instancia de esa clase que es el padre de `frame` que a su vez es el padre de `frame_txt` padre del `Text`. Es decir, `self.bind('<Control-b>', self.parent.master.master.ejecutar_proceso)` y `menu.add_command(label="Ejecutar", command=self.parent.master.master.ejecutar_proceso)`. También puedes hacer que el inicializador de `MyText` reciba como argumento la referencia a la instancia de de `MainApp`.

Comment: En cuanto a los nombres de las teclas para los eventos de teclado puedes mirarte: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html y http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm.

Comment: Vale, en cuanto al ERROR que creía era debido a lo de `tk.call` no era por eso sino que había tenido un error de teclado al faltarme cerrar con > en líneas con algo como <Control-z> por eso me daba el error de _tkinter.TclError: missing ">" in binding.

Comment: Por lo de la referencia a otro método de la clase padre. A ver si te entiendo bien ... ¿tendría que poner una referencia ".master" por cada widget padre que tenga en la clase padre hasta llegar al elemento Text en cuestión? En el ejemplo del post lo puse de forma sencilla pero en el proyecto, dentro de la clase padre, tengo el "text_01" que está dentro de un "frame_txt_01" que, a su vez, está dentro de otro "frame_txt" que está dentro de otro llamado "frame" que está dentro del ROOT principal (self) ... ¿Entonces? ¿Sería algo así? `self.parent.master.master.master.ejecutar_proceso` ¿Esta bien?

Comment: ¿Un ejemplito de lo de "También puedes hacer que el inicializador de MyText reciba como argumento la referencia a la instancia de de MainApp" para verlo mejor?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78303/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-zacktagnan).

Comment: A ver ... si esto que sigue `self.bind('<F3>', self.ejecutar_metodo)` sería para aplicar `self.ejecutar_metodo()` al pulsar la tecla [F3], ¿cómo es para que se aplique al soltar la tecla [F3]? He probado varias combinaciones como la de `<F3-KeyRelease>`, pero me da este ERROR: `TclError: extra characters after detail in binding`.

Comment: @zacktagnan casi XD... Debe ser `"<KeyRelease-F3>"`