# Acción de buscar, buscar todo, buscar siguiente, buscar anterior en un Text

Tags: python, tkinter

Dentro de un editor de texto, estoy implementando lo típico de "Buscar todas las ocurrencias", "Buscar", "Buscar Anterior" y "Buscar Siguiente".

Este es el código, (es un código basado en la respuesta de otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169725/establecer-atajos-de-teclado-en-botones-de-men%C3%BA) que hice):

```
# encoding: utf-8

'''
####### Python 3 #######
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
'''
''''''
####### Python 2 #######
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont  

entr_str = tk.Entry()

def beep_error(f):
    '''
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    '''
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)
        # Para las búsquedas...
        #    -> Buscar todas las ocurrencias
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-f>', self.buscar_todo)
        #    -> Buscar la primera ocurrencia
        self.bind('<Control-f>', self.buscar(True, False))
        #    -> Buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
        self.bind('<F3>', self.buscar(False, False))
        #    -> Buscar la anterior ocurrencia
        self.bind('<Shift-F3>', self.buscar(False, True))


        # Para Búsqueda simple | Anterior | Siguiente
        self.idx_prev = tk.StringVar()
        self.idx_next = tk.StringVar()
        self.idx_next.set('1.0')

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        '''
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        '''
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Cortar", command=self.cortar)
        menu.add_command(label="Copiar", command=self.copiar)
        menu.add_command(label="Pegar", command=self.pegar)
        menu.add_separator()
        menu.add_command(label="Buscar tod@s", command=self.buscar_todo)
        menu.add_command(label="Buscar...", command=lambda: self.buscar(True, False))
        menu.add_command(label="Buscar Siguiente", command=lambda: self.buscar(False, False))
        menu.add_command(label="Buscar Anterior", command=lambda: self.buscar(False, True))
        menu.tk.call("tk_popup", menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'


    '''
    ¿Cómo accedería al ENTRY desde las dos siguientes funciones si estuviera como
    self.entr_str dentro de MainApp.buscar y no como global " en_str = '' " arriba
    del archivo?
    '''
    # ¿¿Hace falta poner en este método también lo de "event=none"??
    def buscar_todo(self, event=None):
        '''Buscar todas las ocurrencias en el Entry de MainApp'''
        global entr_str

        # eliminar el tag 'found', si existiera
        self.tag_remove('found', '1.0', tk.END)
        # obtener la cadena a buscar (no buscar estando vacía)
        s = entr_str.get()
        if s:
            # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
            idx = '1.0'
            while 1:
                # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia, salir del loop si no hay más
                idx = self.search(s, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not idx: break
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                idx = lastidx
            # poner de color rojo la fuente de las ocurrencias etiquetadas
            self.tag_config('found', foreground='red')
        # dando el foco al campo de entrada de texto
        entr_str.focus_set()

    def buscar(self, f_ini=True, _backward=False, event=None):
        '''Buscar ocurrencia en el Entry de MainApp'''
        global entr_str

        # eliminar el tag 'found', si existiera
        self.tag_remove('found', '1.0', tk.END)
        # obtener la cadena a buscar (no buscar estando vacía)
        s = entr_str.get()
        if s:
            # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
            if f_ini:
                self.idx_next.set('1.0')
            #print('- idx_next >> {}'.format(self.idx_next.get()))

            # # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia
            if(_backward == False):
                idx = self.search(s, self.idx_next.get(), nocase=1)
            else:
                idx = self.search(s, self.idx_prev.get(), nocase=1, backwards=True)
            # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
            lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))
            # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
            self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
            # preparar para buscar la anterior ocurrencia
            self.idx_prev.set(self.idx_next)
            # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
            self.idx_next.set(lastidx)

            # poner de color rojo la fuente de las ocurrencias etiquetadas
            self.tag_config('found', foreground='red')
        # dando el foco al campo de entrada de texto
        entr_str.focus_set()



class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Editar', menu=editmenu, underline=0)

        findmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Buscar', menu=findmenu, underline=0)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )

        editmenu.add_command(label='Deshacer',
                            command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Rehacer',
                            command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label='Cortar',
                            command=self.text_01.cortar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Copiar',
                            command=self.text_01.copiar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Pegar',
                            command=self.text_01.pegar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Seleccionar todo',
                            command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                            )

        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar',
                            command=lambda: self.buscar('Simple'),
                            accelerator='Ctrl+F'
                            )
        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar todo',
                            command=lambda: self.buscar('All'),
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+F'
                            )

        # Cargando un texto de prueba
        text_01_contenido = '''Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.'''
        self.text_01.insert(1.0, text_01_contenido)


    def buscar(self, tipo='Simple'):

        busca_top_w = 350
        busca_top_h = 80
        busca_top_x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (busca_top_w / 2)
        busca_top_y = (self.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (busca_top_h / 2)

        busca_top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        busca_top.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(busca_top_w, busca_top_h, busca_top_x, busca_top_y))
        busca_top.config(bg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
        busca_top.resizable(0,0)

        self.busca_frm_tit = tk.Frame(busca_top, bg='grey', pady=5)
        self.busca_frm_tit.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

        # ¿¿Cómo centrar este Frame o su contenido??
        self.busca_frm_content = tk.Frame(busca_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.busca_frm_content.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

        if(tipo == 'Simple'):
            busca_top.title('Buscar...')
            buscar_01_txt = '~ Buscar ~'
        elif(tipo == 'All'):
            busca_top.title('Buscar tod@s...')
            buscar_01_txt = '~ Buscar tod@s ~'

        buscar_01_msg = tk.Message(self.busca_frm_tit, text=buscar_01_txt, bg='grey', padx=10, pady=0)
        buscar_01_msg.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        buscar_01_msg.config(width=240, justify='center', font=('Consolas', 14, 'bold'))

        entr_str = tk.Entry(self.busca_frm_content)
        entr_str.grid(row=0, column=0)

        if(tipo == 'Simple'):
            self.btn_buscar = tk.Button(self.busca_frm_content, text='Buscar', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar(True, False))
            self.btn_buscar.grid(row=0, column=1)
            self.btn_buscar_prev = tk.Button(self.busca_frm_content, text='<|', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar(False, True))
            self.btn_buscar_prev.grid(row=0, column=2)
            self.btn_buscar_next = tk.Button(self.busca_frm_content, text='|>', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar(False, False))
            self.btn_buscar_next.grid(row=0, column=3)
        elif(tipo == 'All'):
            self.btn_buscar = tk.Button(self.busca_frm_content, text='Buscar tod@s', command=self.text_01.buscar_todo)
            self.btn_buscar.grid(row=0, column=1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

En otra prueba que tengo sin class, me funcionaba el "buscar_todo", el "buscar" y el "buscar siguiente". Ahora, dentro de las class, tampoco me funcionan. Supongo porque la forma de acceder o disponer el "entr_str" no es la correcta que, seguro, debería estar dentro del método MainApp.buscar como self.entr_str y, luego, de alguna forma acceder a él desde la class MyText.

(ahora, no sé si como en el post del que viene éste [ver referencia más arriba], si, también, la mejor solución es, en este caso, un widget virtual de tipo Entry que enlace con el Entry que se encuentra en el método "buscar()" de "MainApp"), o si es mejor pasar, en el inicializador del MyText(), una referencia a la class MainApp(), es decir, `MyText(frame_txt, app=self ...)` y, luego, `self.app=app` y, finalmente, `self.app.entr_str` para acceder así al elemento deseado del método "buscar()" de "MainApp()" )

Lo que si que no me funcionaba tampoco antes en la prueba sencilla sin class es el botón de "buscar anterior".

**NOTA Extra:** como cosas simples, también, tengo la pregunta de cómo centrar el contenido del `self.busca_frm_content`.

> He escrito un poco rápido el código para exponer la pregunta, por eso, los posibles fallos simples que pudiera haber. Pido perdón por ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras informarme más, probar algo más, y simplificar algo, así me queda mi solución a lo que planteaba:

```
# encoding: utf-8

'''
####### Python 3 #######
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox
'''
''''''
####### Python 2 #######
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import tkMessageBox as MessageBox


def beep_error(f):
    '''
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    '''
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, app=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.app = app

        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)

        # Para Búsqueda Total | Anterior | Siguiente
        self.idx_gnral = tk.StringVar()
        pos_cursor = self.index(tk.INSERT)
        self.idx_gnral.set(pos_cursor)

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        '''
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        '''
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Cortar", command=self.cortar)
        menu.add_command(label="Copiar", command=self.copiar)
        menu.add_command(label="Pegar", command=self.pegar)
        menu.tk.call("tk_popup", menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'


    '''
    ¿Cómo accedería al ENTRY desde las dos siguientes funciones si estuviera como
    self.entr_str dentro de MainApp.buscar y no como global " en_str = '' " arriba
    del archivo?
    '''
    def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar todas las ocurrencias en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # eliminar toda marca establecida, si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevos resultados
        self.tag_remove('found', '1.0', tk.END)
        self.tag_remove('found_prev_next', '1.0', tk.END)

        if txt_buscar:
            # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
            idx = '1.0'
            while True:
                # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia, salir del loop si no hay más
                idx = self.search(txt_buscar, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not idx: break
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(txt_buscar))
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                idx = lastidx
            # configurando la forma de etiquetar las ocurrencias encontradas
            self.tag_config('found', background='dodgerblue')

        else:
            MessageBox.showinfo('Info', 'Establecer algún criterior de búsqueda.')

    def buscar_prev(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar previa ocurrencia en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # Tratar índice por si viniera buscar_next()
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.idx_gnral.get().replace('+', '-'))

        # eliminar el tag 'found_prev_next', si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevo resultado
        self.tag_remove('found_prev_next', '1.0', tk.END)

        if txt_buscar:
            idx = self.search(txt_buscar, self.idx_gnral.get(), nocase=1, backwards=True)
            # Siempre que haya una coincidencia
            if(idx != ''):
                # Para hacer SCROLL hasta el resultado de la búsqueda
                # si ésta no estuviera visible
                self.see(idx)
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(txt_buscar))
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found_prev_next', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la anterior ocurrencia
                lastidx_prev = '%s-%dc' % (idx, len(txt_buscar))
                self.idx_gnral.set(lastidx_prev)

                # establecer la marca distintiva para la ocurrencia a etiquetar
                self.tag_config('found_prev_next', background='orangered')

        else:
            MessageBox.showinfo('Info', 'Establecer algún criterio de búsqueda.')

    def buscar_next(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar siguiente ocurrencia en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # Tratar índice por si viniera buscar_prev()
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.idx_gnral.get().replace('-', '+'))

        # eliminar el tag 'found_prev_next', si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevo resultado
        self.tag_remove('found_prev_next', '1.0', tk.END)

        if txt_buscar:
            idx = self.search(txt_buscar, self.idx_gnral.get(), nocase=1)
            # Siempre que haya una coincidencia
            if(idx != ''):
                # Para hacer SCROLL hasta el resultado de la búsqueda
                # si ésta no estuviera visible
                self.see(idx)
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(txt_buscar))
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found_prev_next', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                self.idx_gnral.set(lastidx)

                # establecer la marca distintiva para la ocurrencia a etiquetar
                self.tag_config('found_prev_next', background='orangered')

        else:
            MessageBox.showinfo('Info', 'Establecer algún criterio de búsqueda.')


class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # Combinación de teclas para abrir el panel de "Buscar"
        self.bind('<Control-f>', self.buscar)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Editar', menu=editmenu, underline=0)

        findmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Buscar', menu=findmenu, underline=0)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, app=self, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )

        editmenu.add_command(label='Deshacer',
                            command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Rehacer',
                            command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label='Cortar',
                            command=self.text_01.cortar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Copiar',
                            command=self.text_01.copiar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Pegar',
                            command=self.text_01.pegar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Seleccionar todo',
                            command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                            )

        editmenu.add_separator()

        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar',
                            command=self.buscar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+F'
                            )

        # Cargando un texto de prueba
        text_01_contenido = '''[INICIO]
        Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.

        [ES el FIN]'''
        self.text_01.insert(1.0, text_01_contenido)


    # El EVENT se pone NONE para que pueda llamarse al método
    # cuando no sea por el evento de combinación de teclas especificado.
    # En este caso, para que se pueda abrir, también, por el menú
    def buscar(self, event=None):
        '''Panel de búsqueda de términos en el Text'''

        busca_top_w = 360
        busca_top_h = 80
        busca_top_x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (busca_top_w / 2)
        busca_top_y = (self.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (busca_top_h / 2)

        self.busca_top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        # Considerando evento de cierre de la ventana
        self.busca_top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_closing_busca_top)
        self.busca_top.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(busca_top_w, busca_top_h, busca_top_x, busca_top_y))
        self.busca_top.config(bg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.busca_top.resizable(0,0)

        self.busca_frm_tit = tk.Frame(self.busca_top, bg='grey', pady=5)
        self.busca_frm_tit.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

        # ¿¿Cómo centrar este Frame o su contenido??
        self.busca_frm_content = tk.Frame(self.busca_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.busca_frm_content.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

        self.busca_top.title('Buscar...')
        buscar_01_txt = '~ Buscar ~'

        buscar_01_msg = tk.Message(self.busca_frm_tit, text=buscar_01_txt, bg='grey', padx=10, pady=0)
        buscar_01_msg.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        buscar_01_msg.config(width=240, justify='center', font=('Consolas', 14, 'bold'))

        self.entr_str = tk.Entry(self.busca_frm_content)
        self.entr_str.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3)

        # Si hay un texto seleccionado...
        if(self.text_01.tag_ranges('sel')):
            TXT_seleccionado = self.text_01.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
            # Cuando el contenido seleccionado posee caracteres con tildes u otro
            # tipo de caracteres raros, el FORMAT puede dar el ERROR de:
            #   >> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
            #       (siendo el texto que dió el ERROR >> "cuántas")
            ##print('TXT_seleccionado: [{}]'.format(TXT_seleccionado))
            # Para que no se produzca ese ERROR:
            #   >> o se codifica el contenido pasado al FORMAT() con un ENCODE:
            ####print('TXT_seleccionado: [{}]'.format(TXT_seleccionado.encode('utf-8')))
            #   >> o se emplea esta otra forma de pasar datos a la cadena a imprimir:
            # https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations
            #       => %s, para pasar cadenas.
            #       => %d, para pasar enteros decimales.
            #       => %i, ¿igual que el anterior?.
            #       => %f, para pasar flotantes decimales.
            #       => ...
            print('TXT_seleccionado: [%s]' % (TXT_seleccionado))
            # Rellenando la caja si hay algo seleccionado en el Text
            self.entr_str.insert(0, TXT_seleccionado)

        '''
        Opciones para obtener el contenido seleccionado en un Widget como Text
        (posiblemente válido para otros como el Entry [igual, también, el Label])

            - Cuando se selecciona algo en un Text, el sistema de Tkinter, automáticamente, marca ese contenido seleccionado con la etiqueta de "sel"
            de tal forma que, para seleccionarlo bastaría indicar el primer índice de la marca y el último tal como sigue:
                text.get('sel.first', 'sel.last')
                    que equivale a:
                        text.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
                        (omitir "tk." según sea la forma de importar Tkinter)
            No obstante, si no hay nada seleccionado o, más exactamente, si no hay nada
            "etiquetado" ("tagged") con "sel", puede producirse el siguiente ERROR
                >> TclError: text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"

                >> Para comprobar si algo está seleccionado de esta forma, luego,
                marcado con la etiqueta "sel", se puede emplear el método
                    text.tag_ranges('sel')
                que comprobará si algo del contenido del Text tiene asignada dicha
                etiqueta.

            - Siempre que haya algo seleccionado:
                text.selection_get() (método genérico para todos los widgets)
                    Pero puede no funcionar del todo correctamente, ya que, si no
                    hay nada seleccionado, devuelve la siguiente línea de código
                    sin saber (al menos, YO) por qué hace eso.
                    >> No se ha encontrado (al menos, YO) una forma de comprobar si
                    la selección se cumple o no.
        '''

        self.btn_buscar = tk.Button(self.busca_frm_content, text='Buscar', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar_todo(self.entr_str.get()))
        self.btn_buscar.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3)
        self.btn_buscar_prev = tk.Button(self.busca_frm_content, text='<|', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar_prev(self.entr_str.get()))
        self.btn_buscar_prev.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=3)
        self.btn_buscar_next = tk.Button(self.busca_frm_content, text='|>', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar_next(self.entr_str.get()))
        self.btn_buscar_next.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=3)

        self.entr_str.focus_set()

    def on_closing_busca_top(self):
        '''En el momento de cerrar el cuadro de búsqueda'''
        if MessageBox.askokcancel('Quit', 'Do you want to quit?'):
            # borrando toda etiqueta establecida en los resultados de búsqueda
            self.text_01.tag_remove('found', '1.0', tk.END)
            self.text_01.tag_remove('found_prev_next', '1.0', tk.END)
            # cerrando búsqueda
            self.busca_top.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

Espero que pueda servirle a alguien más que a mí. Saludos.

Comment: He puesto una funcionalidad en la carga del panel del buscador que consiste en cargar el contenido seleccionado en el `Text` (si lo hubiera), como contenido inicial del `Entry` del buscador. Y haciendo diversas pruebas me he percatado que esto funciona bien si llamo al buscador por la opción del Menú pero si lo llamo con "CTRL+F", **NO** se carga ese contenido por defecto ... ¿por qué? ... He abierto otra **[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172286/establecer-dentro-de-un-entry-el-contenido-seleccionado-en-un-text)** por si alguien quisiera esclarecer esta duda. Gracias.

Comment: La pregunta del anterior comentario se solucionó (**[respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172286/establecer-dentro-de-un-entry-el-contenido-seleccionado-en-un-text/172436#172436)**)