# Establecer dentro de un Entry el contenido seleccionado en un Text

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy terminando de implementar un típico buscador en un editor de texto.

La llamada para abrir el panel del buscador se puede hacer desde la opción de menú disponible "Buscar >> Buscar" o con la combinación de teclas "CTRL+F".

Al llamar al buscador es cuando se construye todo su panel con todos los elementos necesarios (botones, caja de entrada, etc.).
Y, dentro de la misma construcción del panel, considero el hecho si existe algo seleccionado en el `Text`, para cargarlo como contenido inicial del `Entry` del buscador.

(siendo `self.text_01` el nombre del `Text` y `` el del Entry del buscador)

```
    # ...

    # Si hay un texto seleccionado...
    if(self.text_01.tag_ranges('sel')):
        TXT_seleccionado = self.text_01.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
        self.entr_str.insert(0, TXT_seleccionado)

    # ...
```

La consideración de combinación de teclas para que se abra el panel del buscador la pongo así:

```
    # Combinación de teclas para abrir el panel de "Buscar"
    self.bind('<Control-f>', self.buscar)
```

**[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170207/acci%c3%b3n-de-buscar-buscar-todo-buscar-siguiente-buscar-anterior-en-un-text/171941#171941)** se puede ver el código completo al que me refiero (que ya existe como respuesta a otra de mis preguntas).

Y la pregunta sería ¿por qué SI se me llega a cargar, inicialmente, en el `Entry`, el contenido seleccionado en el `Text` si accedo por la opción del Menú pero **NO** se carga si accedo por la combinación de teclas "CTRL+F"?

¿Qué faltaría hacer para que se cargara, adecuadamente, por ambas opciones?
(siempre que hubiera algo seleccionado en el `Text`, claro está)

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero hay que tener en cuenta que la combinación <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> es una de las combinaciones de teclas predefinidas para `tkinter.Text` y en realidad el efecto es exactamente el mismo que pulsar <kbd>▶</kbd>.

Si te fijas, cuando pulsas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> el cursor avanza un carácter a la derecha del último carácter seleccionado y después se abre la ventana secundaria. Los eventos en Tkinter se propagan en el siguiente orden:

1. Instancia del widget en el que se produce el evento.
2. Clase del widgets en el que se genera el evento.
3. Widget padre del widget en el que se genera el evento.
4. Bindings definidos mediante  `.bind_all()`.

El error en tu caso está en que creas el enlace a nivel de instancia de `MainApp`:

```
self.bind('<Control-f>', self.buscar)
```

Por lo que cuando se genera el evento, primero se llama el binding de la clase del widget `self.text_01` (avanza el cursor en un carácter) y después el evento se propaga a su widget padre, en este caso la instancia de `MainApp` y se produce la llamada a `self.buscar`. Claro que ya no sirve de nada porque al mover el cursor un carácter toda selección se pierde...

La solución es muy simple en realidad, realiza el binding a nivel de `self.text_01`, en el `__init__` de `MainApp` en cualquier momento después de declarar `self.text_01` haz:

```
self.text_01.bind('<Control-f>', self.buscar)
```

y elimina  `self.bind('<Control-f>', self.buscar)`.

Esto sobreescribe el binding por defecto asociado a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> en `tkinter.Text`.

Recuerda que si quieres que el evento no se propague (en este caso no importa ya que `tkinter.Tk` no tiene definido binding alguno para <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) debes hacer que `self.buscar` (o el método que sea) retorne "break":

```
self buscar(self, event=None):
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return "break"
```

Comment: Justo iba a editar la pregunta pues, aparte, de lo que preguntaba también me había fijado en lo que dices, que al pulsar CRT+F el cursor avanza una posición, que con CTRL+MAY+F se selecciona el siguiente carácter, que el CTRL+H funciona como un BACKSPACE (otra combinación de teclas que me da problemas y que quería usar para abrir el panel de "Buscar y Reemplazar"). Investigando, me han salido ciertos posts que hablan de los bindtags, de cómo eliminar los eventos por defecto de un widget, de cómo cambiar el orden ... (sigo en el siguiente comentario)

Comment: enlaces a los posts a los que me refiero ([enlace-01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326766/remove-tkinter-text-default-binding), [enlace-02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200), [enlace-03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501849/how-to-bind-self-events-in-tkinter-text-widget-after-it-will-binded-by-text-widg)) ... De primeras, había probado a poner lo del `return "break"` ... pero no funcionaba, igual, por lo que dices de que el tkinter no tiene definido ese binding.

Comment: También, había probado la solución de eliminar los bindings por defeto del elemento Text (en mi caso, el self.text_01) con las instrucciones que se reflejan en uno de los enlaces que he especificado (...`bindtags.remove("Text")`...) pero esto elimina tanto que ya no se puede ni escribir, ni seleccionar texto dentro del Text. Lo que no sé es si es posible no eliminar todos los de por defecto sino, solamente, los que se deseen. ¿es posible? si es así y lo sabes, ¿cómo sería? Por último, ya iba a optar por cambiar de combinación de teclas (en vez de CTRL+H, usar CTRL+R). Vale, probaré tu consejo.

Comment: Para que `return "break"` funcione tu binding debe estar **a nivel del widget a partir del cual quieres romper la propagación del evento**. Eliminar todos los bindstags es generalmente contraproducente como as podido observar. Puedes sobreescribir la respuesta a cualquier evento preestablecido siguiendo la misma idea que muestro, solo recuerda **el binding debes hacerlo a nivel de ese widget**, no en su ventana padre. Si solo quieres eliminar el binding predeterminado puedes hacer los siguiente `self.text_01.bind('<Control-b>', lambda e: "break")`, (en este caso para para Ctrl + B).

Comment: Tengo otro problema rápido referido a los Bindings ... Lo pongo en dos comentarios seguidos: ... Tengo el Text que forma parte de una especie de formulario que el usuario rellena antes de lanzar un proceso. El proceso se puede lanzar pulsando un botón, por un submenú y quería también que se lanzara con la combinación de teclas CTRL+B. Todas las opciones llaman a un método "verif_form_datos". (continúa en el siguiente comentario)

Comment: Interpreto que, en este caso, el BIND va vinculado al objeto raíz. Luego, dentro de mi clase principal `MainApp(tk.Tk)` he puesto `self.bind('<Control-b>', self.verif_form_datos)` pero tras arrancar la aplicación, al pulsar CTRL+B me sale el ERROR de `TypeError: verif_form_datos() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` Si no me equivoco me dice que le estoy pasando dos argumentos ¿cómo? ¿cuál es mi error entonces si el método solo recibe el `self`? (`def verif_form_datos(self):`) ... Poniéndolo así no da error pero no se ejecuta nada ... `self.bind('<Control-b>', lambda x: self.verif_form_datos)`

Comment: Primero, si vinculas el evento al objeto raiz pero el Text tiene un bind propio para Ctrl + b (por defecto lo tiene) primero se ejecutará el del Text (mover cursor al carácter anterior) y luego el de su padre (el que tu defines) si pulsa Ctrl +b con el **foco en el Text**, como pasa en tu problema inicial. Segundo, el método recibe un parámetro que es el evento que causa su llamada (además de `self` si es un método de instancia), luego debes  definirlo `def verif_form_datos(self, event=None)`, al darle un valor por defecto a `event` puede ser llamado mediante `self.verif_form_datos()` también.

Comment: Si era eso, que me olvidaba de poner el event=None tal como has puesto. Gracias por refrescarme la memoria. El otro día me pasó igual porque me había olvidado lo mismo. ... :)