# Contador de resultados de búsqueda en un Text de Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, contador

Partiendo del **[código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170207/acci%C3%B3n-de-buscar-buscar-todo-buscar-siguiente-buscar-anterior-en-un-text/171941#171941)** de la respuesta que aporte a mi propia pregunta "Acción de buscar, buscar todo, buscar siguiente, buscar anterior en un Text", sobre como montar un buscador sobre el contenido de un Text de Tkinter, ahora, quisiera añadirle la funcionalidad de que tuviera un contador, por ejemplo, dentro del panel emergente de búsqueda, por encima de la caja (Entry) que sirve para insertar el texto a buscar.

Un contador del estilo: [**1** de **32**]
Siendo **1** el primer resultado de búsqueda y **32** el total de resultados de búsqueda.
Pero, también, teniendo en el buscador los botones de "Anterior" y "Siguiente" de resultado de búsqueda, quisiera que esto se reflejara en el contador de modo que, si se pulsa en el botón de "Siguiente", el contador pasara a [**2** de **32**]. Y si se pulsa en el botón de "Anterior", pues, volviera uno para atrás, osea, [**1** de **32**].

La complicación que no veo como resolver es la de enumerar los resultados de búsqueda para que el número indicador de situación pueda ir para adelante o para atrás.

Decir por último que el inicio de la enumeración no tendría por que empezar siempre por el primero, osea [**1** de **32**], a no ser que el cursor estuviera al principio del contenido o antes del primer resultado de búsqueda.
Es decir que si el cursor está colocado antes del resultado **14**, entonces, la primera aparición del contador sería [**14** de **32**]. Osea, tener en cuenta la posición del cursor para reflejar o enumerar la primera coincidencia más cercana del cursor.

Entonces, ¿alguien me podría dar alguna idea de cómo hacerlo? ¿Algún ejemplo?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

este es el código con el contador demandado aparte de otras mejoras con respecto al código del que se partía:

```
# encoding: utf-8

'''
####### Python 3 #######
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox
'''
''''''
####### Python 2 #######
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import tkMessageBox as MessageBox


def beep_error(f):
    '''
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    '''
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)

        # Para Búsqueda Total | Anterior | Siguiente
        self.idx_gnral = tk.StringVar()
        pos_cursor = self.index(tk.INSERT)
        self.idx_gnral.set(pos_cursor)
        self.posic_result = tk.StringVar()

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        '''
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        '''
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label='Cortar', command=self.cortar)
        menu.add_command(label='Copiar', command=self.copiar)
        menu.add_command(label='Pegar', command=self.pegar)
        menu.tk.call('tk_popup', menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Copy>>')
        self.see('insert')
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Cut>>')
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Paste>>')
        self.see('insert')
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
        return 'break'


    '''
    Aún no he conseguido que me salga alguna forma de acceder desde esta class
    al elemento ENTRY [entr_str_busca] ubicado en el bus_reem_top de la class MainApp
    '''
    def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''
        Buscar todas las ocurrencias tecleadas en el Entry de MainApp  
        dentro del contenido del Text:
            -> txt_buscar, el texto a buscar.
            -> RETURN: marcar todas las coincidencias encontradas
                y devuelve el total de coincidencias
                y posición siguiente.'''

        # eliminar toda marca establecida, si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevos resultados
        self.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])

        # Reiniciar idx_gnral desde la posición del cursor
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.index(tk.INSERT))

        # Almacén de posiciones de resultados
        self.dicc_posic_results = {}
        i_posic_results = 1

        # Contador total de resultados
        cont_results = 0

        if txt_buscar:
            # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
            idx = '1.0'
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            while True:
                # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia, salir del loop si no hay más
                idx = self.search(txt_buscar, idx, count=len_ocurr, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not idx: break
                # Almacenando posición de resultado
                self.dicc_posic_results[i_posic_results] = idx
                i_posic_results += 1
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                idx = lastidx
                cont_results += 1
            # configurando la forma de etiquetar las ocurrencias encontradas
            self.tag_config('found', background='dodgerblue')

            self.buscar_next(txt_buscar, 'buscar_todo')

        l_XX_de_tot = []
        if(cont_results > 0):
            l_XX_de_tot = [self.posic_result.get(), cont_results]
        return l_XX_de_tot

    def buscar_prev(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar previa ocurrencia del texto pasado en el contenido principal:
            -> txt_buscar, el texto a buscar.
            -> RETURN: marcar la anterior coincidencia encontrada
                y devuelve la posición anterior.'''

        # Tratar índice por si viniera buscar_next()
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.idx_gnral.get().replace('+', '-'))

        # eliminar el tag 'found_prev_next', si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevo resultado
        self.elim_tags(['found_prev_next'])

        if txt_buscar:
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            idx = self.search(txt_buscar, self.idx_gnral.get(), count=len_ocurr, nocase=1, backwards=True)
            # Siempre que haya una coincidencia
            if(idx != ''):
                # Para hacer SCROLL hasta el resultado de la búsqueda
                # si ésta no estuviera visible
                self.see(idx)
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found_prev_next', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la anterior ocurrencia
                lastidx_prev = '%s-%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                self.idx_gnral.set(lastidx_prev)

                # establecer la marca distintiva para la ocurrencia a etiquetar
                self.tag_config('found_prev_next', background='orangered')

                # Localizar posición de la coincidencia entre los resultados
                self.get_posic_result(idx)
                return self.posic_result.get()

    def buscar_next(self, txt_buscar=None, _from=None):
        '''Buscar siguiente ocurrencia del texto pasado en el contenido principal:
            -> txt_buscar, el texto a buscar.
            -> RETURN: marcar la siguiente coincidencia encontrada
                y devuelve la posición siguiente.'''

        # Tratar índice por si viniera buscar_prev()
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.idx_gnral.get().replace('-', '+'))

        # eliminar el tag 'found_prev_next', si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevo resultado
        self.elim_tags(['found_prev_next'])

        if txt_buscar:
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            idx = self.search(txt_buscar, self.idx_gnral.get(), count=len_ocurr, nocase=1)
            # Siempre que haya una coincidencia
            if(idx != ''):
                # Para hacer SCROLL hasta el resultado de la búsqueda
                # si ésta no estuviera visible
                self.see(idx)
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found_prev_next', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                self.idx_gnral.set(lastidx)

                # establecer la marca distintiva para la ocurrencia a etiquetar
                self.tag_config('found_prev_next', background='orangered')

                # Localizar posición de la coincidencia entre los resultados
                self.get_posic_result(idx)
                if(_from is None):
                    return self.posic_result.get()

    def get_posic_result(self, idx):
        '''
        Posicionar la coincidencia dentro del total de resultados de la búsqueda:
            -> idx, índice de la coincidencia encontrada.'''

        for _i_posic_ in self.dicc_posic_results:
            if(idx == self.dicc_posic_results[_i_posic_]):
                self.posic_result.set(_i_posic_)
                break

    def del_posic_result(self, idx):
        '''
        Eliminar elemento del dicc_posic_results al reemplazar la coincidencia:
            -> idx, índice de la coincidencia a eliminar.'''

        # Eliminar elemento
        for _i_posic_ in self.dicc_posic_results:
            if(str(idx) == str(self.dicc_posic_results[_i_posic_])):
                del self.dicc_posic_results[_i_posic_]
                break

        # Reestructurar diccionario
        _i_del_ = 1
        dicc_del = {}
        for _i_posic_ in self.dicc_posic_results:
            dicc_del[_i_del_] = self.dicc_posic_results[_i_posic_]
            _i_del_ += 1
        self.dicc_posic_results = dicc_del

    def reemplazar(self, txt_buscar=None, txt_reemplazar=None, all=None):
        '''
        Reemplazo de ocurrencia(s) de un término por otro término:
            -> txt_buscar, el texto a buscar.
            -> txt_reemplazar, el texto con el que reemplazar
            toda coicidencia encontrada.
            -> all, para indicar si el reemplazo es total
            o parcial.'''

        # Sin importar que txt_reemplazar sea None o vacío
        coords=[]
        if(all):
            l = list(self.tag_ranges('found'))
        else:
            l = list(self.tag_ranges('found_prev_next'))
        # dándole la vuelta a la lista de índices marcados
        # para poder construir bien las coordenadas
        l.reverse()
        while l:
            coords.append([l.pop(),l.pop()])
        if(all):
            # para un buen reemplazo múltiple, mejor empezar por el final
            coords.reverse()
        for start, end in coords:
            self.delete(start, end)
            self.insert(start, txt_reemplazar)
        if(all is None):
            # Eliminar elemento del dicc_posic_results
            # y reestructurar el diccionario
            self.del_posic_result(start)

            self.buscar_next(txt_buscar, 'reemplazar')
            l_XX_de_tot = []
            if(len(self.dicc_posic_results) > 0):
                l_XX_de_tot = [self.posic_result.get(), len(self.dicc_posic_results)]
        else:
            l_XX_de_tot = self.buscar_todo(txt_buscar)
        return l_XX_de_tot

    def elim_tags(self, l_tags):
        '''Eliminar etiqueta(s) pasada(s) que estén marcando el contenido.'''
        if(len(l_tags) > 0):
            for l_tag in l_tags:
                #   -> para eliminar toda posible etiqueta establecida a lo largo del contenido
                if(self.tag_ranges(l_tag)):
                    self.tag_delete(l_tag)



class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Editar', menu=editmenu, underline=0)

        findmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Buscar', menu=findmenu, underline=0)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )

        self.text_01.bind('<Control-f>', lambda x: self.buscar_reemplazar(False))
        self.text_01.bind('<Control-h>', lambda x: self.buscar_reemplazar(True))

        editmenu.add_command(label='Deshacer',
                            command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Rehacer',
                            command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label='Cortar',
                            command=self.text_01.cortar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Copiar',
                            command=self.text_01.copiar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Pegar',
                            command=self.text_01.pegar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Seleccionar todo',
                            command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                            )

        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar',
                            command=self.buscar_reemplazar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+F'
                            )
        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar y Reemplazar',
                            command=lambda: self.buscar_reemplazar(True),
                            accelerator='Ctrl+H'
                            )

        # Cargando un texto de prueba
        text_01_contenido = '''[INICIO]
        01- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        02- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        03- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        04- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        05- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        06- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.

        [ES el FIN]'''
        self.text_01.insert(1.0, text_01_contenido)

        # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
        self.bus_reem_top_on = False


    def buscar_reemplazar(self, con_reemplazo=None, event=None):
        '''
        Panel de búsqueda/reemplazo de términos en el contenido principal:
            -> con_reemplazo, para cargar o no el apartado de
            "Reemplazar" buscado por otro.'''

        if(self.bus_reem_top_on is False):

            bus_reem_top_w = 365
            bus_reem_top_h = 76
            bus_reem_top_tit = 'Buscar'
            bus_reem_top_msg_w = 240
            if(con_reemplazo):
                bus_reem_top_w = 430
                bus_reem_top_h = 114
                bus_reem_top_tit = 'Buscar y Reemplazar'
            bus_reem_top_x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)# - (bus_reem_top_w / 2)
            bus_reem_top_y = (self.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (bus_reem_top_h / 2)

            self.bus_reem_top = tk.Toplevel(self)
            # Considerando evento de cierre de la ventana
            self.bus_reem_top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_closing_bus_reem_top)
            self.bus_reem_top.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(bus_reem_top_w, bus_reem_top_h, bus_reem_top_x, bus_reem_top_y))
            self.bus_reem_top.config(bg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_top.resizable(0,0)

            self.bus_reem_frm_tit = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_frm_tit.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            # ¿¿Cómo centrar este Frame o su contenido??
            self.bus_reem_frm_busca = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_frm_busca.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            self.bus_reem_top.title('{}...'.format(bus_reem_top_tit))

            # Contador resultados de búsqueda
            self.bus_reem_num_results = tk.StringVar()
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ Sin resultados ~')

            bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit, textvariable=self.bus_reem_num_results, bg='grey', padx=10, pady=0)
            bus_reem_top_msg.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
            bus_reem_top_msg.config(width=bus_reem_top_msg_w, justify='center', font=('Consolas', 10, 'bold'))

            self.entr_str_busca = tk.Entry(self.bus_reem_frm_busca)
            self.entr_str_busca.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3)

            # Si hay un texto seleccionado...
            if(self.text_01.tag_ranges('sel')):
                TXT_seleccionado = self.text_01.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
                # Rellenando la caja si hay algo seleccionado en el Text
                self.entr_str_busca.insert(0, TXT_seleccionado)

            self.btn_buscar_todo = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='Buscar', command=self.buscar_todo_num_results)
            self.btn_buscar_todo.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3)
            self.btn_buscar_prev = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='<|', command=self.buscar_prev_posic)
            self.btn_buscar_prev.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=3)
            self.btn_buscar_next = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='|>', command=self.buscar_next_posic)
            self.btn_buscar_next.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=3)

            self.entr_str_busca.focus_set()

            # Bindings
            # Considerando evento tras soltar cualquier tecla pulsada
            # dentro del entr_str_busca
            self.entr_str_busca.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>', self.on_entr_str_busca_key_release)
            self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F2>', self.buscar_prev_posic)
            self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F3>', self.buscar_next_posic)

            if(con_reemplazo):
                self.bus_reem_frm_reempl = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
                self.bus_reem_frm_reempl.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

                self.entr_str_reempl = tk.Entry(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl)
                self.entr_str_reempl.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3)
                self.btn_reemplazar_next = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl, text='Reemplazar', command=self.bus_reem_posic)
                self.btn_reemplazar_next.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2)
                self.btn_reemplazar_todo = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl, text='Reemplazar todo', command=lambda: self.bus_reem_posic(True))
                self.btn_reemplazar_todo.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=2)

            # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
            self.bus_reem_top_on = True

        # Para que el evento no se propague
        return 'break'

    def buscar_todo_num_results(self):
        '''
        Encontrar todas las coincidencias del término tecleado:
            -> Obtener el Total de resultados de la búsqueda
            y la primera posición si hubiera resultados.'''
        tot = self.text_01.buscar_todo(self.entr_str_busca.get())
        self.set_XX_de_tot(tot)

    def buscar_prev_posic(self, event=None):
        '''Marca la previa coincidencia del resultado de la búsqueda.  
        Indica la posición de la misma.'''
        posic = self.text_01.buscar_prev(self.entr_str_busca.get())
        self.set_XX_de_tot(None, posic)

        # Para que el evento no se propague
        return 'break'

    def buscar_next_posic(self, event=None):
        '''Marca la siguiente coincidencia del resultado de la búsqueda.  
        Indica la posición de la misma.'''
        posic = self.text_01.buscar_next(self.entr_str_busca.get())
        self.set_XX_de_tot(None, posic)

        # Para que el evento no se propague
        return 'break'

    def bus_reem_posic(self, all=None):
        '''Reemplaza la coincidencia señalada, marca la siguiente  
        si la hubiera e indica la posición de la misma.'''

        if(all):
            tot = self.text_01.reemplazar(self.entr_str_busca.get(), self.entr_str_reempl.get(), all)
        else:
            tot = self.text_01.reemplazar(self.entr_str_busca.get(), self.entr_str_reempl.get())
        self.set_XX_de_tot(tot)

    def set_XX_de_tot(self, _tot=None, _posic=None):
        '''Mostrar el "XX de tot coincidencias" si hubiera.  
        Sino, mostrar que no hay resultados.'''

        if(_tot is not None):

            if(len(_tot) > 0):
                self._tot_results = _tot[1]
                msg_XX_de_tot = '~ {} ~'.format('{} de {} coincidencias')
                self.bus_reem_num_results.set(msg_XX_de_tot.format(_tot[0], self._tot_results))
            else:
                self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ Sin resultados ~')

        else:

            if(_posic is not None):
                #       lng >> 'XX de tot coincidencias'
                msg_XX_de_tot = '~ {} ~'.format('{} de {} coincidencias')
                self.bus_reem_num_results.set(msg_XX_de_tot.format(_posic, self._tot_results))

    def on_entr_str_busca_key_release(self, event):
        '''
        Para evitar que el evento de soltar tecla
        no se propague ni a [F2] y ni a [F3].'''
        if event.keycode != 68 and event.keycode != 69:  # F2 y F3 NO 113 114
            print('====================================')
            print('Dentro del IF')
            print('event.keycode y event.char de tecla pulsada: [{}]-[{}]'.format(event.keycode, event.char))
            self.buscar_todo_num_results()
            return 'break'
        #else:
        #    print('====================================')
        #    print('Dentro del ELSE')
        #    print('[{}]-[{}]'.format(event.keycode, event.char))

    def on_closing_bus_reem_top(self):
        '''En el momento de cerrar el cuadro de búsqueda'''
        if MessageBox.askokcancel('Salir', '¿Quiere cerrar la búsqueda?'):
            # borrando toda etiqueta establecida en los resultados de búsqueda
            self.text_01.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])
            # cerrando búsqueda
            self.bus_reem_top.destroy()

            # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
            self.bus_reem_top_on = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

Pequeña explicación:

```
def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None)
```

Dentro de este método, se ha añadido dentro del `while` una variable `cont_results` que irá contando el total de coincidencias si es que hubiera.

Al mismo tiempo, se almacena los index de las coincidencias encontradas gracias a esto:

```
            # Almacenando posición de resultado
            self.dicc_posic_results[i_posic_results] = idx
            i_posic_results += 1
```

Al final de este método, se devuelve una lista con los datos de la posición de la primera coincidencia encontrada respecto a dónde se encuentre el cursor en ese momento y, también, el total de coincidencias:

```
    l_XX_de_tot = []
    if(cont_results > 0):
        l_XX_de_tot = [self.posic_result.get(), cont_results]
    return l_XX_de_tot
```

La primera posición que se almacena dentro `self.posic_result`, en este caso, es calculado gracias a la llamada que se hace con `self.buscar_next(txt_buscar, 'buscar_todo')`.

Dentro de los métodos `def buscar_prev(self, txt_buscar=None)` y `def buscar_next(self, txt_buscar=None, _from=None)` es dónde se llama al cálculo de la posición de la coincidencia recorrida con respecto al número total de coincidencias encontradas:

```
            # Localizar posición de la coincidencia entre los resultados
            self.get_posic_result(idx)
```

A la hora de reemplzar términos encontrados por otros, el diccionario en el que se almacenaron los index de las coincidencias encontradas debería ir reduciéndose para poder reflejar datos actualizados en el contador a mostrar en el panel de búsqueda. Para esa labor está este método:

```
def del_posic_result(self, idx):
    '''
    Eliminar elemento del dicc_posic_results al reemplazar la coincidencia:
        -> idx, índice de la coincidencia a eliminar.'''

    # Eliminar elemento
    for _i_posic_ in self.dicc_posic_results:
        if(str(idx) == str(self.dicc_posic_results[_i_posic_])):
            del self.dicc_posic_results[_i_posic_]
            break

    # Reestructurar diccionario
    _i_del_ = 1
    dicc_del = {}
    for _i_posic_ in self.dicc_posic_results:
        dicc_del[_i_del_] = self.dicc_posic_results[_i_posic_]
        _i_del_ += 1
    self.dicc_posic_results = dicc_del
```

A este método, se le pasa el index `start` de la tag que se está eliminando.

Como se elimina un elemento del diccionario que como clave tiene la posición de cada una de las coincidencias y como valor el index de la misma, para que las posiciones sigan siendo correlativas, se vuelve a reestructurar el diccionario.

En la parte de la `class` principal, dentro de los métodos llamados al pulsar cada uno de los botones del panel de Buscar/Reemplazar, se recoge la lista de valores devuelta. Si se trata del total de coincidencias, se almacena el valor en variable para que pueda ser recuperado por los métodos necesarios.
Y solo queda formatear el texto para que muestre algo como [11 de 50] o [Sin resultados].

Ahí queda para todo al que le pueda servir.