# Incompatibilidades en buscador sobre un Text de Tkinter y mostrar contador

Tags: python, tkinter

Partiendo del **[código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170207/acci%C3%B3n-de-buscar-buscar-todo-buscar-siguiente-buscar-anterior-en-un-text/171941#171941)** de una respuesta (establecida por mí) a de **[una](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170207/acci%C3%B3n-de-buscar-buscar-todo-buscar-siguiente-buscar-anterior-en-un-text)** de mis preguntas, he llegado a mejorar el panel de buscador del código introduciendo ciertas mejoras y funciones (que según se teclea el nuevo término ya busque, acción de reemplazar, atajos de teclado, ...)

El código queda así:

```
# encoding: utf-8

'''
####### Python 3 #######
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox
'''
''''''
####### Python 2 #######
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import tkMessageBox as MessageBox


def beep_error(f):
    '''
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    '''
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, app=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.app = app

        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)

        # Para Búsqueda Total | Anterior | Siguiente
        self.idx_gnral = tk.StringVar()
        pos_cursor = self.index(tk.INSERT)
        self.idx_gnral.set(pos_cursor)

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        '''
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        '''
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Cortar", command=self.cortar)
        menu.add_command(label="Copiar", command=self.copiar)
        menu.add_command(label="Pegar", command=self.pegar)
        menu.tk.call("tk_popup", menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'


    def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar todas las ocurrencias en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # eliminar toda marca establecida, si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevos resultados
        self.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])

        # Reiniciar idx_gnral desde la posición del cursor
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.index(tk.INSERT))

        if txt_buscar:
            # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
            idx = '1.0'
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            while True:
                # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia, salir del loop si no hay más
                idx = self.search(txt_buscar, idx, count=len_ocurr, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not idx: break
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                idx = lastidx
            # configurando la forma de etiquetar las ocurrencias encontradas
            self.tag_config('found', background='dodgerblue')

            self.buscar_next(txt_buscar)

        # Con el EVENTO establecido en el Entry, se ve menos necesario este aviso.
        # Incluso, puede resultar molesto.
        ####else:
        ####    MessageBox.showinfo('Info', 'Establecer algún criterio de búsqueda.')

    def buscar_prev(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar previa ocurrencia en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # Tratar índice por si viniera buscar_next()
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.idx_gnral.get().replace('+', '-'))

        # eliminar el tag 'found_prev_next', si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevo resultado
        self.elim_tags(['found_prev_next'])

        if txt_buscar:
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            idx = self.search(txt_buscar, self.idx_gnral.get(), count=len_ocurr, nocase=1, backwards=True)
            # Siempre que haya una coincidencia
            if(idx != ''):
                # Para hacer SCROLL hasta el resultado de la búsqueda
                # si ésta no estuviera visible
                self.see(idx)
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found_prev_next', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la anterior ocurrencia
                lastidx_prev = '%s-%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                self.idx_gnral.set(lastidx_prev)

                # establecer la marca distintiva para la ocurrencia a etiquetar
                self.tag_config('found_prev_next', background='orangered')

        # Con el EVENTO establecido en el Entry, se ve menos necesario este aviso.
        # Incluso, puede resultar molesto.
        ####else:
        ####    MessageBox.showinfo('Info', 'Establecer algún criterio de búsqueda.')

    def buscar_next(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar siguiente ocurrencia en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # Tratar índice por si viniera buscar_prev()
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.idx_gnral.get().replace('-', '+'))

        # eliminar el tag 'found_prev_next', si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevo resultado
        self.elim_tags(['found_prev_next'])

        if txt_buscar:
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            idx = self.search(txt_buscar, self.idx_gnral.get(), count=len_ocurr, nocase=1)
            # Siempre que haya una coincidencia
            if(idx != ''):
                # Para hacer SCROLL hasta el resultado de la búsqueda
                # si ésta no estuviera visible
                self.see(idx)
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found_prev_next', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                self.idx_gnral.set(lastidx)

                # establecer la marca distintiva para la ocurrencia a etiquetar
                self.tag_config('found_prev_next', background='orangered')

        # Con el EVENTO establecido en el Entry, se ve menos necesario este aviso.
        # Incluso, puede resultar molesto.
        ####else:
        ####    MessageBox.showinfo('Info', 'Establecer algún criterio de búsqueda.')

    def reemplazar(self, txt_buscar=None, txt_reemplazar=None, all=None):
        '''Reemplazo de ocurrencia(s) por otro término'''

        coords=[]
        if(all):
            l = list(self.tag_ranges('found'))
            print('** antes del REVERSE **:')
            for l_i in l:
                print l_i
        else:
            l = list(self.tag_ranges('found_prev_next'))
        # dándole la vuelta a la lista de índices marcados
        # para poder construir bien las coordenadas
        l.reverse()
        print('** tras del REVERSE **:')
        for l_i in l:
            print l_i
        while l:
            coords.append([l.pop(),l.pop()])
        print('** COORDS **:')
        for start, end in coords:
            print('%s, %s' % (start, end))
        print('DENTRO DEL FOR ... COORDS')
        if(all):
            # para un buen reemplazo múltiple, mejor empezar por el final
            coords.reverse()
        for start, end in coords:
            print('%s, %s' % (start, end))
            self.delete(start, end)
            self.insert(start, txt_reemplazar)
        if(all is None):
            self.buscar_next(txt_buscar)

    def elim_tags(self, l_tags):
        '''Eliminar etiqueta(s) pasada(s)'''
        if(len(l_tags) > 0):
            for l_tag in l_tags:
                self.tag_delete(l_tag)



class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Editar', menu=editmenu, underline=0)

        findmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Buscar', menu=findmenu, underline=0)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, app=self, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )

        self.text_01.bind('<Control-f>', lambda x: self.buscar_reemplazar(False))
        self.text_01.bind('<Control-h>', lambda x: self.buscar_reemplazar(True))

        editmenu.add_command(label='Deshacer',
                            command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Rehacer',
                            command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label='Cortar',
                            command=self.text_01.cortar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Copiar',
                            command=self.text_01.copiar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Pegar',
                            command=self.text_01.pegar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Seleccionar todo',
                            command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                            )

        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar',
                            command=self.buscar_reemplazar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+F'
                            )
        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar y Reemplazar',
                            command=lambda: self.buscar_reemplazar(True),
                            accelerator='Ctrl+H'
                            )

        # Cargando un texto de prueba
        text_01_contenido = '''[INICIO]
        01- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        02- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        03- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        04- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        05- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        06- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.

        [ES el FIN]'''
        self.text_01.insert(1.0, text_01_contenido)

        # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
        self.bus_reem_top_on = False


    def buscar_reemplazar(self, con_reemplazo=None, event=None):
        '''Panel de búsqueda/reemplazo de términos en el Text'''

        if(self.bus_reem_top_on is False):

            bus_reem_top_w = 360
            bus_reem_top_h = 80
            bus_reem_top_tit = 'Buscar'
            bus_reem_top_msg_w = 240
            if(con_reemplazo):
                bus_reem_top_h = 120
                bus_reem_top_tit = 'Buscar y Reemplazar'
                bus_reem_top_msg_w = 280
            bus_reem_top_x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (bus_reem_top_w / 2)
            bus_reem_top_y = (self.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (bus_reem_top_h / 2)

            self.bus_reem_top = tk.Toplevel(self)
            # Considerando evento de cierre de la ventana
            self.bus_reem_top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_closing_bus_reem_top)
            self.bus_reem_top.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(bus_reem_top_w, bus_reem_top_h, bus_reem_top_x, bus_reem_top_y))
            self.bus_reem_top.config(bg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_top.resizable(1,1)

            self.bus_reem_frm_tit = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_frm_tit.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            # ¿¿Cómo centrar este Frame o su contenido??
            self.bus_reem_frm_busca = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_frm_busca.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            self.bus_reem_top.title('{}...'.format(bus_reem_top_tit))
            bus_reem_top_head = '~ {} ~'.format(bus_reem_top_tit)

            bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit, text=bus_reem_top_head, bg='grey', padx=10, pady=0)
            bus_reem_top_msg.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
            bus_reem_top_msg.config(width=bus_reem_top_msg_w, justify='center', font=('Consolas', 14, 'bold'))

            self.entr_str_busca = tk.Entry(self.bus_reem_frm_busca)
            self.entr_str_busca.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3)

            # Si hay un texto seleccionado...
            if(self.text_01.tag_ranges('sel')):
                TXT_seleccionado = self.text_01.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
                # Rellenando la caja si hay algo seleccionado en el Text
                self.entr_str_busca.insert(0, TXT_seleccionado)

            self.btn_buscar_todo = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='Buscar', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar_todo(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
            self.btn_buscar_todo.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3)
            self.btn_buscar_prev = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='<|', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar_prev(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
            self.btn_buscar_prev.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=3)
            self.btn_buscar_next = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='|>', command=lambda: self.text_01.buscar_next(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
            self.btn_buscar_next.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=3)

            self.entr_str_busca.focus_set()

            # Bindings
            # Considerando evento tras soltar cualquier tecla pulsada
            # dentro del entr_str_busca
            self.entr_str_busca.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>', lambda x: self.text_01.buscar_todo(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
            ####self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F2>', lambda x: self.text_01.buscar_prev(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
            ####self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F3>', lambda x: self.text_01.buscar_next(self.entr_str_busca.get()))

            if(con_reemplazo):
                self.bus_reem_frm_reempl = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
                self.bus_reem_frm_reempl.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

                self.entr_str_reempl = tk.Entry(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl)
                self.entr_str_reempl.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3)
                self.btn_reemplazar_next = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl, text='Reemplazar', command=lambda: self.text_01.reemplazar(self.entr_str_busca.get(), self.entr_str_reempl.get()))
                self.btn_reemplazar_next.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2)
                self.btn_reemplazar_todo = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl, text='Reemplazar todo', command=lambda: self.text_01.reemplazar(self.entr_str_busca.get(), self.entr_str_reempl.get(), True))
                self.btn_reemplazar_todo.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=2)

            # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
            self.bus_reem_top_on = True

        # Para que el evento no se propague
        return 'break'

    def on_closing_bus_reem_top(self):
        '''En el momento de cerrar el cuadro de búsqueda'''
        if MessageBox.askokcancel('Quit', '¿Cerrar el panel de búsqueda?'):
            # borrando toda etiqueta establecida en los resultados de búsqueda
            self.text_01.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])
            # cerrando búsqueda
            self.bus_reem_top.destroy()

            # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
            self.bus_reem_top_on = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

Esto funciona bien:

- se abre un panel de buscador tanto por la opción de menú [Buscar >> Buscar] y [Buscar >> Buscar y Reemplazar], o por la combinación de teclas [CTRL+F] y [CTRL+H], respectivamente.
- si se abre con algo seleccionado, se busca por ese término.
- se inicia una nueva búsqueda según se teclea algo dentro del Entry.
- se marca la primera coincidencia desde el punto dónde se encuentre el cursor dentro del Text.
- y otras mejoras...

Como digo, todo va bien hasta que añado atajos de teclado ("Bindings") al panel del buscador para activar las acciones vinculadas a los botones de `self.btn_buscar_prev` y `self.btn_buscar_next` de esta forma:
(en el bloque de código anterior están comentadas)

```
        self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F2>', lambda x: self.text_01.buscar_prev(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
        self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F3>', lambda x: self.text_01.buscar_next(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
```

Una vez añadidas estas dos líneas, en principio, sigue funcionando bien todo. Pero lo que no funciona es que, al pulsar (o más bien, soltar) [F2] o [F3] haga lo mismo que sus respectivos botones de [<|] y [|>].
Por ejemplo, el [F2], en vez de ir a la coincidencia a la coincidencia previa como hace si se pulsa el botón correspondiente, hace un extraño. Lo mismo pasa al pulsar [F3].

Funciona mal, pero en la terminal no se muestra error alguno.

Me he percatado que parece haber una incompatibilidad entre aplicar los dos Bindings de los botones de Anterior y Siguiente con estas dos líneas dentro de `def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):`:

```
    # ...
    # Reiniciar idx_gnral desde la posición del cursor
    self.idx_gnral.set(self.index(tk.INSERT))
    #...
        self.buscar_next(txt_buscar)
```

De tal forma que, si comento estas dos líneas, la acción de los Bindings hacia las teclas de [F2] y [F3] vuelve a funcionar bien. Pero, claro, entonces, me quedo sin la funcionalidad de que se marque la primera coincidencia automáticamente.

Luego, ¿que tendría que corregir o hacer para que ambas cosas fueran compatibles?, ¿alguien ve por qué pasa esto y cómo corregirlo?

---

[**Editado**]

Por otro lado, estoy tratando de establecer una especie de contador de resultados de la búsqueda, tal y como expongo en otra **[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173504/contador-de-resultados-de-b%C3%BAsqueda-en-un-text-de-tkinter)**.

Modificando así el bloque de `def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):` para que cuente los resultados de búsqueda y los guarde en una variable `cont_results`:

```
def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):
    '''Buscar todas las ocurrencias en el Entry de MainApp'''

    # eliminar toda marca establecida, si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevos resultados
    self.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])

    # Reiniciar idx_gnral desde la posición del cursor
    self.idx_gnral.set(self.index(tk.INSERT))

    if txt_buscar:
        # Contador total de resultados
        cont_results = 0
        # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
        idx = '1.0'
        len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
        while True:
            # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia, salir del loop si no hay más
            idx = self.search(txt_buscar, idx, count=len_ocurr, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
            if not idx: break
            # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
            lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
            # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
            self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
            # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
            idx = lastidx
            cont_results += 1
        # configurando la forma de etiquetar las ocurrencias encontradas
        self.tag_config('found', background='dodgerblue')

        self.buscar_next(txt_buscar)
```

Entonces, quisiera que ese valor se reflejara en la cabecera del panel del buscador.
Para ello, he modificado, en la construcción del panel, estas líneas

```
        bus_reem_top_head = '~ {} ~'.format(bus_reem_top_tit)

        bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit, text=bus_reem_top_head, bg='grey', padx=10, pady=0)
```

por estas otras (en las que se añade, también, una StringVar())

```
        ####bus_reem_top_head = '~ {} ~'.format(bus_reem_top_tit)
        # Contador resultados de búsqueda
        self.bus_reem_num_results = tk.StringVar()
        self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))

        bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit, text=self.bus_reem_num_results.get(), bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=10, pady=0)
```

Por tanto, quisiera pasar el valor de la variable `cont_results` que reside en el método `buscar_todo()` de la `class MyText()` a la variable de tipo `StringVar()` que está dentro del `def buscar_reemplazar()` de la `class MainApp()`.

Aprovechando que paso `class MainApp()` como `app` en la construcción de la `class MyText()`, he tratado de acceder a la mencionada StringVar() pero no he conseguido, aún y todo, que coja el valor deseado con esta línea al final del bloque de `def buscar_todo()`:

```
        #...
        self.buscar_next(txt_buscar)
        # Reflejando cantidad de resultados
        self.app.bus_reem_num_results.set('X de {}'.format(cont_results))
        print('self.app.bus_reem_num_results >> [{}]'.format(self.app.bus_reem_num_results.get()))
```

Solo consigo que salga el valor por la terminal pero no en el lugar del panel de buscador deseado. ¿Alguien sabe cómo conseguirlo?

Saludos.

Comment: No puedo probar nada por no tener un pc a mano, pero el problema si no me equivoco es `self.entr_str_busca.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>', ....)`, este evento entra en conflicto con los de `f2` y `f3`, más que conflicto es que cuando pulsas f3 y lo sueltas ambos eventos se generan y ambas funciones se ejecutan, igual para f2.

Comment: No sé, ojalá pudieras probarlo en otro momento en un PC y te aseguraras. Como digo, si comento, dentro de `def buscar_todo()`, la línea que reinicia el `idx_gnral` y la que llama a `self.buscar_next(txt_buscar)`, los eventos de F2 y F· no chocan con el de ``entry` que dices y funcionan bien los 3. Pero una vez que habilito eso de que se marque el primer resultado de búsqueda, entonces, los eventos de F2 y F3 dejan de funcionar bien ... Y ¿sabes algo sobre lo de pasar el valor de `cont_results` al `self.bus_reem_num_results`? ¡¡Ojalá puedas responderme!! Aunque tenga que esperar a mañana.

Comment: De todas formas, si fuera como dices, tener un evento con la combinación de `<Any-KeyRelease>` sería incompatible con cualquier otra combinación ¿no? Pues, por ejemplo, al hacer CTRL+G, al soltar G, se aplicaría el evento de `<Any-KeyRelease>` ya que G entra como Any y al soltar se aplicaría KeyRelease, ¿esto es lo que pasa?. Osea que si quieres ese evento `<Any-KeyRelease>`, ¿no puedes tener otros?

Comment: He creado una respuesta zacktagman, no me gusta responder sin probar el código pero creo que esto debe solucionar el problema, no obstante es posible que algo se me escara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto al primer problema, la causa está en que hay dos eventos que se generan cuando las teclas <kbd>F2</kbd> y <kbd>F3</kbd> son pulsadas:

- `self.entr_str_busca.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>'...)` causa que el evento sea generado cuando **cualquier tecla es soltada**, incluidas por supuesto <kbd>F2</kbd> y <kbd>F3</kbd> cuando el foco está en el *Entry* `entr_str_busca`.
- `self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F2>', ...)` y `self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F3>', ...)` ocasionan que se lancen los eventos correspondientes cuando se suelta <kbd>F2</kbd> y <kbd>F3</kbd> respectivamente en la *TopLevel* `bus_reem_top`, **padre de `entr_str_busca`**.

Cuando se pulsa y suelta <kbd>F2</kbd> o <kbd>F3</kbd> la callback asociada a    `'<Any-KeyRelease>'` es llamada primero porque es el evento asociado al propio widget, **como el evento sigue propagándose** las callbacks asociadas a los eventos`'<KeyRelease-F2>'` y `'<KeyRelease-F3>'` del widget padre son también llamadas. Esto causa el comportamiento extraño, ya que antes de ejecutar `self.text_01.buscar_prev` y `self.text_01.buscar_next` se llama a `self.text_01.buscar_todo`.

**Esto no ocurriría si ambos eventos tuvieran el mismo widget de origen**, en cuyo caso solo las callbacks asociadas a `'<KeyRelease-F2>'` y `'<KeyRelease-F3>'` se ejecutarían.

Si quieres que `'<Any-KeyRelease>'` esté asociado al *Text* mientras que los eventos para <kbd>F2</kbd> y <kbd>F3</kbd> lo estén a su padre, lo que puedes hacer es bloquear la propagación del evento en el hijo para aquellas teclas que no sean estas dos:

```
self.entr_str_busca.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>', self.on_entr_str_busca_key_release)
self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F2>', lambda x: self.text_01.buscar_prev(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F3>', lambda x: self.text_01.buscar_next(self.entr_str_busca.get()))
```

después creamos el siguiente método en la clase `MainApp`:

```
 def on_entr_str_busca_key_release(self, event):
    if event.keysym != "F2" and event.keysym != "F3":  # F2 y F3
        self.text_01.buscar_todo(self.entr_str_busca.get())
        return "break"
```

---

En cuanto al segundo problema, hay varias formas de enfocarlo, una muy simple es hacer que `buscar_todo` retorne el contador:

```
    def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar todas las ocurrencias en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # eliminar toda marca establecida, si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevos resultados
        self.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])

        # Reiniciar idx_gnral desde la posición del cursor
        self.idx_gnral.set(self.index(tk.INSERT))

        cont_results = 0

        if txt_buscar:
            # Contador total de resultados
            # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
            idx = '1.0'
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            while True:
                # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia, salir del loop si no hay más
                idx = self.search(txt_buscar, idx, count=len_ocurr, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not idx: break
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                idx = lastidx
                cont_results += 1
            # configurando la forma de etiquetar las ocurrencias encontradas
            self.tag_config('found', background='dodgerblue')

            self.buscar_next(txt_buscar)
        return cont_results
```

Después en `MyApp` añadir un método que actúe de wrapper:

```
def _buscar(self, event=None):
    cont = self.text_01.buscar_todo(self.entr_str_busca.get())
    if cont:
        self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format(cont))
    else:
        self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))
```

y llamarlo en lugar de `self.text_01.buscar_todo` en estos dos puntos:

- Callback del botón  `btn_buscar_todo`:

  ```
  self.btn_buscar_todo = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca,
                                   text='Buscar',
                                   command=self._buscar
                                   )
  ```
- Método `on_entr_str_busca_key_release` del punto anterior:

  ```
  def on_entr_str_busca_key_release(self, event):
      if event.keysym != "F2" and event.keysym != "F3":  # F2 y F3
          self._buscar()
          return "break"
  ```

Por otro lado no debes hacer esto:

```
bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit,
                              text=self.bus_reem_num_results.get(),
                              padx=10, pady=0
                              )
```

con ello el `Message` **recibe el contenido** de la `StringVar` como texto a mostrar, es igual que hacer `text="cadena"`. **Si la `StringVar` es modificada el texto del `Message` no se verá alterado** ya que no está enlazado con la variable en si, debes pasar la propia instancia de la `StringVar` al argumento `textvariable`:

```
bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit,
                              textvariable=self.bus_reem_num_results,
                              padx=10, pady=0)
```

---

### **Edición**

Dado que para poder implementar un contador a las búsquedas necesitas en la práctica buscar toda las coincidencias de una vez, `buscar_next` y `buscar_prev` pierden su utilidad tal y como están. Para implementar los dos métodos anteriores y el contador pueden ser de ayuda los métodos del `Text` `tag_prevranges` y `tag_nextranges` que dadas una etiqueta y un índice o rango de índices buscan la primera aparición de esta etiqueta en el texto.

Una posible implementación podría ser:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
####### Python 3 #######
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox

'''
####### Python 2 #######
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import tkMessageBox as MessageBox



def beep_error(f):
    '''
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    '''
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, app=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.app = app

        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)


        self._ocurrencias_encontradas = []
        self._numero_ocurrencia_actual = None


    @property
    def numero_ocurrencias(self):
        return len(self._ocurrencias_encontradas)

    @property
    def numero_ocurrencia_actual(self):
        return self._numero_ocurrencia_actual

    @property
    def indice_ocurrencia_actual(self):
        tags = self.tag_ranges('found_prev_next')
        return tags[:2] if tags else None

    @indice_ocurrencia_actual.setter
    def indice_ocurrencia_actual(self, idx):
        # establecer la marca distintiva para la ocurrencia a etiquetar
        self.elim_tags(['found_prev_next'])
        self.tag_config('found_prev_next', background='orangered')

        if idx is not None:
            self.tag_add('found_prev_next', *idx)
            self.see(idx[0])
            self._numero_ocurrencia_actual = self._ocurrencias_encontradas.index(self.indice_ocurrencia_actual) + 1
        else:
            self._numero_ocurrencia_actual = None

    @property
    def ocurrencias_encontradas(self):
        return self._ocurrencias_encontradas


    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        '''
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        '''
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Cortar", command=self.cortar)
        menu.add_command(label="Copiar", command=self.copiar)
        menu.add_command(label="Pegar", command=self.pegar)
        menu.tk.call("tk_popup", menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
        self.see("insert")
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'

    def get_index(self, index):
        '''Dado un índice en cualquier formato retorna una tupla (fila -> int, columna -> int)'''
        return tuple(int(idx) for idx in self.index(index).split("."))


    def buscar_todo(self, txt_buscar=None):
        '''Buscar todas las ocurrencias en el Entry de MainApp'''

        # eliminar toda marca establecida, si existiera, antes de plasmar nuevos resultados
        self.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])

        if txt_buscar:
            # Contador total de resultados
            # empezar desde el principio (y parar al llegar al final [stopindex >> END])
            idx = '1.0'
            len_ocurr = tk.IntVar()
            while True:
                # encontrar siguiente ocurrencia, salir del loop si no hay más
                idx = self.search(txt_buscar, idx, count=len_ocurr, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not idx: break
                # index justo después del final de la ocurrencia
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len_ocurr.get())
                # etiquetando toda la ocurrencia (incluyendo el start, excluyendo el stop)
                self.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                # preparar para buscar la siguiente ocurrencia
                idx = lastidx

            # configurando la forma de etiquetar las ocurrencias encontradas
            self.tag_config('found', background='dodgerblue')

        tags = self.tag_ranges('found')
        self._ocurrencias_encontradas = list(zip(*[iter(tags)] * 2))

        self.buscar_next()


    def buscar_prev(self):
        '''Buscar previa ocurrencia en el Entry de MainApp'''
        idx = self.indice_ocurrencia_actual[0] if self.indice_ocurrencia_actual else self.index(tk.INSERT)    
        self.indice_ocurrencia_actual = self.tag_prevrange('found', idx) or self.tag_prevrange('found', self.index(tk.END)) or None


    def buscar_next(self):
        '''Buscar siguiente ocurrencia en el Entry de MainApp'''
        idx = self.indice_ocurrencia_actual[1] if self.indice_ocurrencia_actual else self.index(tk.INSERT)    
        self.indice_ocurrencia_actual = self.tag_nextrange('found', idx) or self.tag_nextrange('found', "0.0") or None


    def reemplazar(self, txt_reemplazar=None, all=False):
        '''Reemplazo de ocurrencia(s) por otro término'''
        if not all and self.indice_ocurrencia_actual is not None:
            start, end = self.indice_ocurrencia_actual
            self._ocurrencias_encontradas.remove(self.indice_ocurrencia_actual)
            self.delete(start, end)
            self.insert(start, txt_reemplazar)
            tags = self.tag_ranges('found')
            self.buscar_next()


        elif all:
            for start, end in reversed(self.ocurrencias_encontradas):
                self.delete(start, end)
                self.insert(start, txt_reemplazar)
                self._ocurrencias_encontradas  = []
                self.indice_ocurrencia_actual = None


    def elim_tags(self, l_tags):
        '''Eliminar etiqueta(s) pasada(s)'''
        for l_tag in l_tags:
            self.tag_delete(l_tag)



class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Editar', menu=editmenu, underline=0)

        findmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Buscar', menu=findmenu, underline=0)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, app=self, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )

        self.text_01.bind('<Control-f>', lambda x: self.buscar_reemplazar(False))
        self.text_01.bind('<Control-h>', lambda x: self.buscar_reemplazar(True))

        editmenu.add_command(label='Deshacer',
                            command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Rehacer',
                            command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                            )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label='Cortar',
                            command=self.text_01.cortar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Copiar',
                            command=self.text_01.copiar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Pegar',
                            command=self.text_01.pegar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                            )
        editmenu.add_command(label='Seleccionar todo',
                            command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                            )

        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar',
                            command=self.buscar_reemplazar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+F'
                            )
        findmenu.add_command(label='Buscar y Reemplazar',
                            command=lambda: self.buscar_reemplazar(True),
                            accelerator='Ctrl+H'
                            )

        # Cargando un texto de prueba
        text_01_contenido = '''[INICIO]
        01- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        02- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        03- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        04- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.


        05- Esto es un contenido de prueba para buscar cualquier texto.

        06- Unas cuántas palabras que forman frases y párrafos en los que buscar concurrencias referidas a los términos buscados.

        [ES el FIN]'''
        self.text_01.insert(1.0, text_01_contenido)

        # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
        self.bus_reem_top_on = False


    def buscar_reemplazar(self, con_reemplazo=None, event=None):
        '''Panel de búsqueda/reemplazo de términos en el Text'''

        if not self.bus_reem_top_on:

            bus_reem_top_w = 360
            bus_reem_top_h = 80
            bus_reem_top_tit = 'Buscar'
            bus_reem_top_msg_w = 240

            if con_reemplazo:
                bus_reem_top_h = 120
                bus_reem_top_tit = 'Buscar y Reemplazar'
                bus_reem_top_msg_w = 280

            bus_reem_top_x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (bus_reem_top_w // 2)
            bus_reem_top_y = (self.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (bus_reem_top_h // 2)

            self.bus_reem_top = tk.Toplevel(self)
            # Considerando evento de cierre de la ventana
            self.bus_reem_top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_closing_bus_reem_top)
            self.bus_reem_top.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(bus_reem_top_w, bus_reem_top_h, bus_reem_top_x, bus_reem_top_y))
            self.bus_reem_top.config(bg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_top.resizable(1,1)

            self.bus_reem_frm_tit = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_frm_tit.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            # ¿¿Cómo centrar este Frame o su contenido??
            self.bus_reem_frm_busca = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
            self.bus_reem_frm_busca.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

            self.bus_reem_top.title('{}...'.format(bus_reem_top_tit))
            self.bus_reem_num_results = tk.StringVar()
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))

            #bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit, textvariable=self.bus_reem_num_results, bg=_cfg__._root_color_quater, padx=10, pady=0)  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<< comentado para no depender de _cgfg__
            bus_reem_top_msg = tk.Message(self.bus_reem_frm_tit, textvariable=self.bus_reem_num_results, padx=10, pady=0)                                 # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            bus_reem_top_msg.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
            bus_reem_top_msg.config(width=bus_reem_top_msg_w, justify='center', font=('Consolas', 14, 'bold'))

            self.entr_str_busca = tk.Entry(self.bus_reem_frm_busca)
            self.entr_str_busca.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3)

            # Si hay un texto seleccionado...
            if self.text_01.tag_ranges('sel'):
                TXT_seleccionado = self.text_01.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
                # Rellenando la caja si hay algo seleccionado en el Text
                self.entr_str_busca.insert(0, TXT_seleccionado)
                self._buscar()
                self._buscar_anterior()

            self.btn_buscar_todo = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='Buscar', command=self._buscar)
            self.btn_buscar_todo.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3)
            self.btn_buscar_prev = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='<|', command=self._buscar_anterior)
            self.btn_buscar_prev.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=3)
            self.btn_buscar_next = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_busca, text='|>', command=self._buscar_siguiente)
            self.btn_buscar_next.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=3)

            self.entr_str_busca.focus_set()

            # Bindings
            # Considerando evento tras soltar cualquier tecla pulsada
            # dentro del entr_str_busca
            self.entr_str_busca.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>', self.on_entr_str_busca_key_release)
            self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F2>', self._buscar_anterior)
            self.bus_reem_top.bind('<KeyRelease-F3>', self._buscar_siguiente)

            if con_reemplazo:
                self.bus_reem_frm_reempl = tk.Frame(self.bus_reem_top, bg='grey', padx=5, pady=5)
                self.bus_reem_frm_reempl.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

                self.entr_str_reempl = tk.Entry(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl)
                self.entr_str_reempl.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3)
                self.btn_reemplazar_next = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl, text='Reemplazar', command=self._reemplazar)
                self.btn_reemplazar_next.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2)
                self.btn_reemplazar_todo = tk.Button(self.bus_reem_frm_reempl, text='Reemplazar todo', command=self._reemplazar_todo)
                self.btn_reemplazar_todo.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=2)

            # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
            self.bus_reem_top_on = True

        # Para que el evento no se propague
        return 'break'

    def on_closing_bus_reem_top(self):
        '''En el momento de cerrar el cuadro de búsqueda'''
        if MessageBox.askokcancel('Quit', '¿Cerrar el panel de búsqueda?'):
            # borrando toda etiqueta establecida en los resultados de búsqueda
            self.text_01.elim_tags(['found', 'found_prev_next'])
            # cerrando búsqueda
            self.bus_reem_top.destroy()

            # Para evitar que se abran más de un panel de bus_reem_top
            self.bus_reem_top_on = False

    def on_entr_str_busca_key_release(self, event):
        if event.keysym != "F2" and event.keysym != "F3":  # F2 y F3
            self._buscar()
            return "break"

    def _buscar(self, event=None):
        self.text_01.buscar_todo(self.entr_str_busca.get())
        if self.text_01.ocurrencias_encontradas:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} de {} ~'.format(self.text_01.numero_ocurrencia_actual, self.text_01.numero_ocurrencias))
        else:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))

    def _buscar_siguiente(self, event=None):
        self.text_01.buscar_next()
        if self.text_01.ocurrencias_encontradas:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} de {} ~'.format(self.text_01.numero_ocurrencia_actual, self.text_01.numero_ocurrencias))
        else:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))

    def _buscar_anterior(self, event=None):
        self.text_01.buscar_prev()
        if self.text_01.ocurrencias_encontradas:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} de {} ~'.format(self.text_01.numero_ocurrencia_actual, self.text_01.numero_ocurrencias))
        else:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))

    def _reemplazar(self, event=None):
        self.text_01.reemplazar(self.entr_str_reempl.get())
        if self.text_01.ocurrencias_encontradas:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} de {} ~'.format(self.text_01.numero_ocurrencia_actual, self.text_01.numero_ocurrencias))
        else:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))

    def _reemplazar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.text_01.reemplazar(self.entr_str_reempl.get(), True)
        if self.text_01.ocurrencias_encontradas:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} de {} ~'.format(self.text_01.numero_ocurrencia_actual, self.text_01.numero_ocurrencias))
        else:
            self.bus_reem_num_results.set('~ {} ~'.format('Sin resultados'))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

el código seguramente es mejorable. Quedan algunas cosas por determinar, por ejemplo, actualmente el `Text` se puede editar mientras se realiza una búsqueda, lo cual puede entrar en conflicto con el manejo de indices en la búsqueda y  los reemplazos. La solución común para esto último es bloquear la edición del texto mientras el formulario de búsqueda/remplazo está abierto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale, lo referido al [F2] y [F3] no me funciona, pasando la misma cosa rara (como si se propagara) (¿lo has probado al fin? Sino, ya me dirás) ... Con respecto a lo del contador, eso si me va, aunque, para completarlo como he puesto en esta **[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173504/contador-de-resultados-de-búsqueda-en-un-text-de-tkinter)**, me gustaría que fuera (habiendo un total de 10) "1 de 10" y que al pulsar `self.btn_buscar_next`, se moviera "2 de 10" y al pulsar otra vez, "3 de 10", ..., etc, y con `self.btn_buscar_prev` retrocediera uno "2 de 10", etc. ¿Sabes cómo?

Comment: Bueno, en cuanto a lo referido a los eventos vinculados a las teclas [F2] y [F3], de nuevo, revisé tu código, ver si lo había copiado bien. Por ese lado, lo había cogido bien. Entre una cosa y otra, me dió por comprobar los `event.keycode` y sus respectivos `event.char`de las teclas pulsadas con un print de esas dos referencias. Total que, al pulsar [F2], no me salió el código **113** como, parece, era de suponer sino el **68** y pulsando [F3] me sale **69** en vez de el **114** que indicaste.

Comment: Y continuando con la prueba, me he percatado que la flecha de Izquierda si que tiene el código de evento **113** y la flecha Derecha el **114**. Antes de hacer esta prueba, también busque sobre como sacar una relación general de códigos de evento. Entre otras webs, llegué a **[esta](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)** que ofrece la prueba de teclear una tecla para que te dé el código correspondiente. Aquí si que corresponde el 113 con [F2] y 114 con [F4]. Entonces, lo de la relación de códigos-teclas ¿es algo universal? o ¿depende del lenguaje, del S.O. o qué?

Comment: @zacktagnan por fin he podido probar el código y he añadido otra posible implementación para las búsquedas. en cuanto a lo que comentas del keycode pues efectivamente es plataforma dependiente, en linux depende por ejemplo de la configuración de teclado que se use... fallo mio... En este caso lo que puedes hacer es usar [keysyms](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) que no debería dar problema para estas teclas.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte sobre la forma de hacer una especie de contador como demandaba. Lo examinaré en otro momento. Ya llegué a resolverlo de otra forma que se me ocurrió. Lo he puesto de respuesta **[aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173504/contador-de-resultados-de-búsqueda-en-un-text-de-tkinter/174284#174284)**. Díme que piensas si tienes tiempo para revisarla.

Comment: Respecto a lo que te comenté de los códigos de evento, si entiendo bien lo que es el código **68** para la tecla [F2] en Linux, en otro S.O. (como Windows), sería otro código (igual el 113, igual otro) ¿Es así?. Entonces, sería un problema. Y la opción sería usar lo que dices los "**keysyms**" Pero no entiendo bien lo expuesto en el enlace que pones. ¿Cómo sería? ¿Tengo que poner en formato keysyms lo que ponía por ejemplo en la línea del `if event.keycode != 68 and event.keycode != 69:`? ¿o dónde? ¿Me lo puedes especificar con un ejemplillo?