# Aplicación Multi idioma - Configurar cambio de idioma

Tags: python, tkinter

Siguiendo y adaptando el código que se suministró, como respuesta a la pregunta **[aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169725/establecer-atajos-de-teclado-en-botones-de-men%C3%BA)** enlazada, lo que estoy tratando de gestionar, ahora, en un típico editor de texto, es el cambio de idioma.

Tengo la siguiente estructura base de archivos
(estructura reducida para este ejemplo de pregunta)

- |
  |--> [*_cfg*_]
  |........|--> _cfg_env_prbs.cfg
  |........|--> a_cfg_ini_prbs.py
  |
  |--> [lng]
  |........|--> lng_en_prbs.py
  |........|--> lng_es_prbs.py
  |
  |--> _cfg_config_prbs.py 
  |--> main.py

[*_cfg*_/**_cfg_env_prbs.cfg**]
Archivo que contiene las variables de entorno del proyecto.

```
[LNG]
lng_dir = lng
lng_ini = es
lng_list = ['en', 'es']

[VARIOS]
ruta_relativa_n0 = ./
ruta_relativa_n1 = ../
```

[*_cfg*_/**a_cfg_ini_prbs.py**]
Archivo que crea el archivo que contiene las variables de entorno del proyecto.

```
# encoding: utf-8

import sys

if sys.version[0] < '3':
    # 2.x
    import ConfigParser

else:
    # 3.x
    import configparser

#from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import os

# ===========================================================

# Limpia consola antes de empezar ejecución
os.system('clear')

# -> Ejecutando desde la raíz del proyecto
CFG_DOC = '__cfg__/_cfg_env_prbs.cfg'
# -> o desde la carpeta del archivo de destino
####CFG_DOC = '_cfg_env_prbs.cfg'
RUTA_ABS = os.getcwd()
RUTA_ABS_CFG_URL = RUTA_ABS + '/' + CFG_DOC


_cfg_ = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

# -----------------------------------------------------
#= [ROOT] ==============================================
# ...
#=======================================================
# -----------------------------------------------------
#= [LNG] ===============================================
lng_secc = 'LNG'
lng_dir = 'lng'
lng_ini = 'es'
lng_list = ['en', 'es']
#=======================================================
# -----------------------------------------------------
#= [DB] ================================================
# ...
#=======================================================
# -----------------------------------------------------
#= [LIBS] ==============================================
# ...
#=======================================================
# -----------------------------------------------------
#= [VARIOS] ============================================
vrs_secc = 'VARIOS'
vrs_ruta_relativa_n0 = './'
vrs_ruta_relativa_n1 = '../'
#=======================================================
# -----------------------------------------------------

_cfg_.add_section(lng_secc)
_cfg_.set(lng_secc, 'lng_dir', lng_dir)
_cfg_.set(lng_secc, 'lng_ini', lng_ini)
_cfg_.set(lng_secc, 'lng_list', lng_list)

_cfg_.add_section(vrs_secc)
_cfg_.set(vrs_secc, 'ruta_relativa_n0', vrs_ruta_relativa_n0)
_cfg_.set(vrs_secc, 'ruta_relativa_n1', vrs_ruta_relativa_n1)


def crear_entorno():
    '''Crear archivo de configuración con variables de entorno.'''
    #Escribiendo el archivo de configuración
    #    -> abierto en modo de escritura (w) binaria (b)
    #    -> el directorio deberá existir antes de ejecutar el comando
    with open(RUTA_ABS_CFG_URL, 'wb') as _cfg_doc_:
        _cfg_.write(_cfg_doc_)

    _cfg_doc_.close()

    print(':: ENTORNO creado correctamente en un primer inicio ::')


# Descomentar siguiente línea para ejecutar desde este archivo
####crear_entorno()
```

[lng/**lng_en_prbs.py**] y [lng/**lng_es_prbs.py**]
Archivos que contienen una estructura de los diversos textos a mostrar según el idioma habilitado, todo por medio de diccionarios.

[lng/**lng_en_prbs.py**]

```
# encoding: utf-8

data = {
    # :: ROOT ::
    'tit': 'My Notepad',

    # :: MENÚS ::
    'editmenu': {
        'txt': 'Edit',
        'submenu': [
            'Undo',
            'Redo',
            'Cut',
            'Copy',
            'Paste',
            'Select all',
            'Preferences'
        ],

        # :: MENÚS :: Contenido de "Preferencias" ::
        'prefer_content': {
            'submenu': [
                [
                    'EN (English)',
                    'ES (Spanish)'
                ],
                'Settings'
            ],
            'title': 'User Preferences ~ ',
            'x': 'x',
            'prefer_btn_ok': 'OK',
            'prefer_btn_cncl': 'Cancel'
        }
    }
}
```

[lng/**lng_es_prbs.py**]

```
# encoding: utf-8

data = {
    # :: ROOT ::
    'tit': 'Mi Notepad',

    # :: MENÚS ::
    'editmenu': {
        'txt': 'Editar',
        'submenu': [
            'Deshacer',
            'Rehacer',
            'Cortar',
            'Copiar',
            'Pegar',
            'Seleccionar todo',
            'Preferencias'
        ],

        # :: MENÚS :: Contenido de "Preferencias" ::
        'prefer_content': {
            'submenu': [
                [
                    'EN (Inglés)',
                    'ES (Español)'
                ],
                'Configuraciones'
            ],
            'title': 'Preferencias de Usuario ~ ',
            'x': 'x',
            'prefer_btn_ok': 'Aceptar',
            'prefer_btn_cncl': 'Cancelar'
        }
    }
}
```

[**_cfg_config_prbs.py**]
Archivo que carga las variables de entorno del proyecto.

```
# encoding: utf-8

"""
Importar
"""
import os
import sys

if sys.version[0] < '3':
    # 2.x

    # Archivo de Entorno
    import ConfigParser

else:
    # 3.x

    # Archivo de Entorno
    import configparser

# Para convertir cadena en diccionario
import ast

# manipular fecha/hora
import datetime


# Recuperando ENTORNO
#-----------------------------------------
CFG_DOC = '__cfg__/_cfg_env_prbs.cfg'


#   -> Creando ENTORNO si aún no existe
if(not os.path.isfile(CFG_DOC)):
    sys.path.insert(1, './__cfg__')
    import a_cfg_ini_prbs as _cfg_ini
    _cfg_ini.crear_entorno()


#   -> Siempre que exista el ENTORNO
if(os.path.isfile(CFG_DOC)):
    RUTA_ABS = os.getcwd()
    RUTA_ABS_CFG_URL = RUTA_ABS + '/' + CFG_DOC
    #-----------------------------------------
    _cfg_ = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    _cfg_.read( RUTA_ABS_CFG_URL )
    #-----------------------------------------
    _ruta_relativa_n0 = _cfg_.get('VARIOS', 'ruta_relativa_n0')
    _ruta_relativa_n1 = _cfg_.get('VARIOS', 'ruta_relativa_n1')
    #-----------------------------------------
    _lng_dir = _ruta_relativa_n0 + _cfg_.get('LNG', 'lng_dir')
    _lng_ini = _cfg_.get('LNG', 'lng_ini')
    _lng_list = ast.literal_eval( _cfg_.get('LNG', 'lng_list') )


    # Otros datos de interés
    #-----------------------------------------
    #   ...


#   -> Siempre que exista el ENTORNO
#   -> y sino
else:
    print(':: ¡¡ATENCIóN!! - Posible(s) problema(s) al intentar crear el ENTORNO ::')
```

[**main.py**]
Archivo principal del proyecto.

```
# encoding: utf-8

"""
####### Python 3 #######
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
"""
""""""
####### Python 2 #######
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

import os
import sys

# Recuperando ENTORNO
#-----------------------------------------
import _cfg_config_prbs as _cfg__

# Capturando ruta de librería de Idiomas
#-----------------------------------------
sys.path.insert(3, _cfg__._lng_dir)
lng_ini = _cfg__._lng_ini
#lng_ini = 'en'
if(lng_ini == 'en'):
    import lng_en_prbs as lng
elif(lng_ini == 'es'):
    import lng_es_prbs as lng
else:
    import lng_es_prbs as lng


def beep_error(f):
    """
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    """
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        """
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        """
        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        #       lng >> 'Cortar'
        menu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][2], command=self.cortar)
        #       lng >> 'Copiar'
        menu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][3], command=self.copiar)
        #       lng >> 'Pegar'
        menu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][4], command=self.pegar)
        menu.tk.call('tk_popup', menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Copy>>')
        self.see('insert')
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Cut>>')
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Paste>>')
        self.see('insert')
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<SelectAll>>')
        #self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')   # < Otra alternativa
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'


class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        #       lng >> 'Editar'
        menubar.add_cascade(label=lng.data['editmenu']['txt'], menu=editmenu, underline=0)

        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                        selectbackground='lightblue',
                        width=44, height=16,
                        bg='#242424', fg='white',
                        insertbackground='white',
                        highlightbackground='black',
                        highlightcolor='white'
                        )

        #       lng >> 'Deshacer'
        editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][0],
                         command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                         accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                         )
        #       lng >> 'Rehacer'
        editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][1],
                         command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                         accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                         )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        #       lng >> 'Cortar'
        editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][2],
                         command=self.text_01.cortar,
                         accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                         )
        #       lng >> 'Copiar'
        editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][3],
                         command=self.text_01.copiar,
                         accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                         )
        #       lng >> 'Pegar'
        editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][4],
                         command=self.text_01.pegar,
                         accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                         )
        #       lng >> 'Seleccionar todo'
        editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][5],
                         command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                         accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                         )
        editmenu.add_separator()
        self.editmenu_prefer = tk.Menu(editmenu, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        #       lng >> 'Preferencias'
        editmenu.add_cascade(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][6], menu=self.editmenu_prefer, underline=0)
        #   [Idiomas]
        self.opc_prefer_lng = tk.StringVar()
        # Predeterminada la establecida en la configuración por defecto
        self.opc_prefer_lng.set('es')
        #       lng >> 'EN (English)'
        opc_pref_lng_en_lbl = '{}'.format(lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][0])
        if(self.opc_prefer_lng.get() == 'en'): opc_pref_lng_en_lbl += ' [*]'
        self.editmenu_prefer.add_radiobutton(label=opc_pref_lng_en_lbl, variable=self.opc_prefer_lng, value='en', command=self.edit_prefer_lng)
        #       lng >> 'ES (Español)'
        opc_pref_lng_es_lbl = '{}'.format(lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][1])
        if(self.opc_prefer_lng.get() == 'es'): opc_pref_lng_es_lbl += ' [*]'
        self.editmenu_prefer.add_radiobutton(label=opc_pref_lng_es_lbl, variable=self.opc_prefer_lng, value='es', command=self.edit_prefer_lng)
        self.editmenu_prefer.add_separator()
        #       lng >> 'Configuraciones'
        self.editmenu_prefer.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][1], command=self.edit_prefer_cfg)


    def edit_prefer_lng(self):
        """Establecer "Preferencias" de Idioma."""
        global lng_ini

        #       lng >> 'EN (English)'
        opc_pref_lng_en_lbl = '{}'.format(lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][0])
        #       lng >> 'ES (Español)'
        opc_pref_lng_es_lbl = '{}'.format(lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][1])
        if(self.opc_prefer_lng.get() == 'en'): opc_pref_lng_en_lbl += ' [*]'
        elif(self.opc_prefer_lng.get() == 'es'): opc_pref_lng_es_lbl += ' [*]'

        self.editmenu_prefer.entryconfig(0, label=opc_pref_lng_en_lbl)
        self.editmenu_prefer.entryconfig(1, label=opc_pref_lng_es_lbl)
        lng_ini = self.opc_prefer_lng.get()


    def edit_prefer_cfg(self):
        """Ventana emergente Preferencias."""

        prefer_top_w = 420
        prefer_top_h = 500
        prefer_top_x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (prefer_top_w / 2)
        prefer_top_y = (self.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (prefer_top_h / 2)

        self.prefer_top = tk.Toplevel()
        self.prefer_top.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(prefer_top_w, prefer_top_h, prefer_top_x, prefer_top_y))
        #       lng >> 'Preferencias de Usuario ~ '
        self.prefer_top.title(lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['title'] + root_tit)
        self.prefer_top.config(bg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
        #self.prefer_top.resizable(0,0)
        self.prefer_top.resizable(1,1)
        self.prefer_top.transient(self)      # only one window in the task bar
        self.prefer_top.grab_set()           # making modal

        #       lng >> 'Aceptar'
        prefer_btn_ok = tk.Button(self.prefer_top, text=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['prefer_btn_ok'], command=self.prefer_guardar)
        prefer_btn_ok.pack(side='left')
        #       lng >> 'Cancelar'
        prefer_btn_cncl = tk.Button(self.prefer_top, text=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['prefer_btn_cncl'], command=self.prefer_top.destroy)
        prefer_btn_cncl.pack(side='right')


    def prefer_guardar(self):

        # Guardando Configuraciones de las Preferencias establecidas
        # ...

        # Cerrando "Preferencias"
        self.prefer_top.destroy()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Limpia consola antes de empezar ejecución
    os.system('clear')

    #       lng >> 'Mi Notepad'
    root_tit = lng.data['tit']
    root = MainApp()
    root.title(root_tit)

    root.mainloop()
```

El idioma por defecto establecido como variable de entorno es el español ('es').

Ahora mismo, para cambiar de idioma, el usuario puede acceder al menú:
Editar >> Preferencias >> (pulsar en el idioma deseado)

Bueno, tras exponer como es toda la estructura de archivos y su contenido, la demanda es saber cómo poder establecer el cambio de idioma con el consiguiente de textos al cambiar de idioma, valga la redundancia.

Osea, ¿cómo establecer el cambio de idioma cuando el usuario chequée un radiobutton diferente al activo dentro de Editar >> Preferencias?

Gracias. Saludos.

Entorno del proyecto: Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.x, Tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras investigar un poquito más de aquí y de allá, y con alguna sugerencia de algún compañero de tareas, he realizado ciertos cambios en el archivo de `main.py` para que ya funcione el cambio de idioma y, con ello, los textos se adecuen al idioma elegido.

[**main.py**]

```
# encoding: utf-8

'''
####### Python 3 #######
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
'''
''''''
####### Python 2 #######
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

import os
import sys


# Recuperando ENTORNO
#-----------------------------------------
import _cfg_config_prbs as _cfg__

# Capturando ruta de librería de Idiomas
#-----------------------------------------
sys.path.insert(3, _cfg__._lng_dir)
lng = ''
import lng_en_prbs
import lng_es_prbs


def beep_error(f):
    '''
    Decorador que permite emitir un beep cuando un método de instancia
    decorado de un widget produce una excepción
    '''
    def applicator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            if args and isinstance(args[0], tk.Widget):
                args[0].bell()
    return applicator


class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.bind('<Control-a>', self.seleccionar_todo)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cortar)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copiar)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.pegar)
        self.bind('<Control-z>', self.deshacer)
        self.bind('<Control-Shift-z>', self.rehacer)
        self.bind("<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.mostrar_menu)

    def mostrar_menu(self, event):
        '''
        Muestra un menú popup con las opciones copiar, pegar y cortar
        al hacer click derecho en el Text
        '''

        menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        #       lng >> 'Cortar'
        menu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][2], command=self.cortar)
        #       lng >> 'Copiar'
        menu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][3], command=self.copiar)
        #       lng >> 'Pegar'
        menu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][4], command=self.pegar)
        menu.tk.call('tk_popup', menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def copiar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Copy>>')
        self.see('insert')
        return 'break'

    def cortar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Cut>>')
        return 'break'

    def pegar(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<Paste>>')
        self.see('insert')
        return 'break'

    def seleccionar_todo(self, event=None):
        self.event_generate('<<SelectAll>>')
        #self.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')   # < Otra alternativa
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def deshacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'undo')
        return 'break'

    @beep_error
    def rehacer(self, event=None):
        self.tk.call(self, 'edit', 'redo')
        return 'break'



class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.set_idioma(_cfg__._lng_ini)

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.editmenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        #       lng >> 'Editar'
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label=lng.data['editmenu']['txt'], menu=self.editmenu, underline=0)


        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.config(padx=10, pady=10)

        frame_txt = tk.Frame(frame, background='black')
        frame_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=12)
        self.text_01 = MyText(frame_txt, wrap=tk.WORD, bd=0, undo=True)
        self.text_01.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.text_01.config(bd=0, padx=6, pady=4, font=self.text_font,
                            selectbackground='lightblue',
                            width=44, height=16,
                            bg='#242424', fg='white',
                            insertbackground='white',
                            highlightbackground='black',
                            highlightcolor='white'
                            )

        #       lng >> 'Deshacer'
        self.editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][0],
                            command=self.text_01.deshacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Z'
                            )
        #       lng >> 'Rehacer'
        self.editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][1],
                            command=self.text_01.rehacer,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+Shift+Z'
                            )
        self.editmenu.add_separator()
        #       lng >> 'Cortar'
        self.editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][2],
                            command=self.text_01.cortar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+X'
                            )
        #       lng >> 'Copiar'
        self.editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][3],
                            command=self.text_01.copiar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+C'
                            )
        #       lng >> 'Pegar'
        self.editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][4],
                            command=self.text_01.pegar,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+V'
                            )
        #       lng >> 'Seleccionar todo'
        self.editmenu.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][5],
                            command=self.text_01.seleccionar_todo,
                            accelerator='Ctrl+A'
                            )
        self.editmenu.add_separator()

        self.editmenu_prefer = tk.Menu(self.editmenu, tearoff=0, bg='black', fg='white')
        #       lng >> 'Preferencias'
        self.editmenu.add_cascade(label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][6], menu=self.editmenu_prefer, underline=0)

        #   [Idiomas]
        self.opc_prefer_lng = tk.StringVar()
        # Predeterminada la establecida en la configuración por defecto
        self.opc_prefer_lng.set(_cfg__._lng_ini)
        # Señalando idioma elegido por defecto
        opc_pref_lng_en_bg_fg = self.set_colors_bg_fg(self.opc_prefer_lng.get(), 'rbtn_en')
        opc_pref_lng_es_bg_fg = self.set_colors_bg_fg(self.opc_prefer_lng.get(), 'rbtn_es')
        #       lng >> 'EN (English)'
        self.editmenu_prefer.add_radiobutton(label=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][0], background=opc_pref_lng_en_bg_fg[0], foreground=opc_pref_lng_en_bg_fg[1], variable=self.opc_prefer_lng, value='en', command=self.edit_prefer_lng)
        #       lng >> 'ES (Español)'
        self.editmenu_prefer.add_radiobutton(label=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][1], background=opc_pref_lng_es_bg_fg[0], foreground=opc_pref_lng_es_bg_fg[1], variable=self.opc_prefer_lng, value='es', command=self.edit_prefer_lng)

        self.editmenu_prefer.add_separator()
        #       lng >> 'Configuraciones'
        self.editmenu_prefer.add_command(label=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][1], command=self.edit_prefer_cfg)


    def set_idioma(self, lng_ini=None):
        '''
        Establecer el idioma a cargar:
            -> lng_ini, el idioma elegido actualmente.
            -> lng, variable global que lleva el archivo
            de idioma importado.'''
        global lng

        # Almacenando librería de Idiomas elegida
        #-----------------------------------------
        if(lng_ini == 'en'):
            lng = lng_en_prbs
        elif(lng_ini == 'es'):
            lng = lng_es_prbs
        else:
            lng = lng_es_prbs


    def carga_idioma(self):
        '''Cargando, en los elementos,los textos adecuados al idioma establecido.'''

        self.title(lng.data['tit'])

        # Sin ver la razón, este elemento, aún siendo el primer hijo
        # del elemento Menu principal, se enumera por 1 en vez de por 0
        self.menubar.entryconfig(1, label=lng.data['editmenu']['txt'])

        self.editmenu.entryconfig(0, label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][0])
        self.editmenu.entryconfig(1, label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][1])
        self.editmenu.entryconfig(3, label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][2])
        self.editmenu.entryconfig(4, label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][3])
        self.editmenu.entryconfig(5, label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][4])
        self.editmenu.entryconfig(6, label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][5])
        self.editmenu.entryconfig(8, label=lng.data['editmenu']['submenu'][6])

        # Señalando idioma elegido
        opc_pref_lng_en_bg_fg = self.set_colors_bg_fg(self.opc_prefer_lng.get(), 'rbtn_en')
        opc_pref_lng_es_bg_fg = self.set_colors_bg_fg(self.opc_prefer_lng.get(), 'rbtn_es')

        #       lng >> 'EN (English)'
        self.editmenu_prefer.entryconfig(0, label=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][0], background=opc_pref_lng_en_bg_fg[0], foreground=opc_pref_lng_en_bg_fg[1])
        #       lng >> 'ES (Español)'
        self.editmenu_prefer.entryconfig(1, label=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][0][1], background=opc_pref_lng_es_bg_fg[0], foreground=opc_pref_lng_es_bg_fg[1])
        #       lng >> 'Configuraciones'
        self.editmenu_prefer.entryconfig(3, label=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['submenu'][1])


    def set_colors_bg_fg(self, _lng=None, _elem=None):
        '''Establecer combinación de colores según idioma elegido:
            -> _lng, idioma elegido.
            -> _elem, elemento al que aplicar los colores.
            -> RETURN: combinación de colores a aplicar.'''

        l_colors_bg_fg = ['black', 'white']

        if((_lng == 'en' and _elem == 'rbtn_en')
            or (_lng == 'es' and _elem == 'rbtn_es')):
            l_colors_bg_fg = ['white', 'black']

        return l_colors_bg_fg


    def edit_prefer_lng(self):
        '''Establecer "Preferencias" de Idioma.'''

        # Estableciendo idioma
        self.set_idioma(self.opc_prefer_lng.get())
        # Recargando textos tras el cambio de idioma
        self.carga_idioma()


    def edit_prefer_cfg(self):
        '''Ventana emergente "Preferencias".'''

        prefer_top_w = 420
        prefer_top_h = 500
        prefer_top_x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (prefer_top_w / 2)
        prefer_top_y = (self.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (prefer_top_h / 2)

        self.prefer_top = tk.Toplevel()
        self.prefer_top.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(prefer_top_w, prefer_top_h, prefer_top_x, prefer_top_y))
        #       lng >> 'Preferencias de Usuario ~ '
        self.prefer_top.title(lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['title'] + root_tit)
        self.prefer_top.config(bg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
        #self.prefer_top.resizable(0,0)
        self.prefer_top.resizable(1,1)
        self.prefer_top.transient(self)      # only one window in the task bar
        self.prefer_top.grab_set()           # making modal

        #       lng >> 'Aceptar'
        prefer_btn_ok = tk.Button(self.prefer_top, text=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['prefer_btn_ok'], command=self.prefer_guardar)
        prefer_btn_ok.pack(side='left')
        #       lng >> 'Cancelar'
        prefer_btn_cncl = tk.Button(self.prefer_top, text=lng.data['editmenu']['prefer_content']['prefer_btn_cncl'], command=self.prefer_top.destroy)
        prefer_btn_cncl.pack(side='right')


    def prefer_guardar(self):

        # Guardando Configuraciones de las Preferencias establecidas
        # ...

        # Cerrando "Preferencias"
        self.prefer_top.destroy()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Limpia consola antes de empezar ejecución
    os.system('clear')

    root = MainApp()
    #       lng >> 'Mi Notepad'
    root_tit = lng.data['tit']
    root.title(root_tit)

    root.mainloop()
```

En resumen, las correcciones a considerar han sido:

El modo de hacer el `import` de las librerías de idiomas ha pasado de ser así

```
# Capturando ruta de librería de Idiomas
#-----------------------------------------
sys.path.insert(3, _cfg__._lng_dir)
lng_ini = _cfg__._lng_ini
#lng_ini = 'en'
if(lng_ini == 'en'):
    import lng_en_prbs as lng
elif(lng_ini == 'es'):
    import lng_es_prbs as lng
else:
    import lng_es_prbs as lng
```

a esto otro

```
# Capturando ruta de librería de Idiomas
#-----------------------------------------
sys.path.insert(3, _cfg__._lng_dir)
lng = ''
import lng_en_prbs
import lng_es_prbs
```

que se complementa con esta función que se encuentra dentro de `class MainApp()`

```
def set_idioma(self, lng_ini=_cfg__._lng_ini):
    '''
    Establecer el idioma a cargar:
        -> lng_ini, el idioma elegido actualmente.
        -> lng, variable global que lleva el archivo
        de idioma importado.'''
    global lng

    # Almacenando librería de Idiomas elegida
    #-----------------------------------------
    if(lng_ini == 'en'):
        lng = lng_en_prbs
    elif(lng_ini == 'es'):
        lng = lng_es_prbs
    else:
        lng = lng_es_prbs
```

Es en esta función dónde se asigna la librería del idioma elegido a la variable global de `lng` que antes se establecía como alias de la librería importada según el `if` del idioma elegido.
Con esto, se logra que el cambio de la librería de idioma pueda ser dinámico.

A esta función con la que se establece el idioma se le llama, inicialmente, en el `__init__` de la clase principal y cuando se quiere cambiar de idioma al pulsar en el radiobutton adecuado dentro del menú de Editar >> Preferencias.

Lo que hay que tener en cuenta, también, es que, tras el cambio de idioma, hay que establecer de nuevo el texto a cada elemento estático que tenga la aplicación. Es lo que se hace dentro del método `carga_idioma()`.

Los demás posibles textos de otros elementos como, en esta aplicación, el menú contextual o la ventana emergente de Editar >> Preferencias >> Configuraciones, se cargan automáticamente con el nuevo idioma cuando son llamados.

Ya, a modo de complemento extra, he añadido una forma de ver más visual el idioma establecido cambiando el color de fondo y fuente del radiobutton seleccionado.

Pues nada, más. Creo que he contado todo. Espero le pueda servir a más gente que busque hacer algo parecido.

Saludos.